# How can I center text (horizontally and vertically) inside a div block?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` set to `display:block` (`90px` `height` and `width`), and I have some text inside.

I need the text to be aligned in the center both vertically and horizontally.

I have tried `text-align:center`, but it doesn't do the vertical centering part, so I tried `vertical-align:middle`, but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I finally found a solution that works with relative sizes and no fixed heights: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16195362/1301331

Comment: It is very important to know how to center / middle elements. The below document has given a very clear picture.
http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center objects within divs, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 1961, accepted):

If it is one line of text and/or image, then it is easy to do. Just use:

```css
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 90px;       /* The same as your div height */
```

That's it. If it can be multiple lines, then it is somewhat more complicated. But there are solutions on  http://pmob.co.uk/. Look for "vertical align".

Since they tend to be hacks or adding complicated divs... I usually use a table with a single cell to do it... to make it as simple as possible.

---

## Update for 2020:

Unless you need make it work on earlier browsers such as Internet Explorer 10, you can use flexbox. It is [widely supported by all current major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). Basically, the container needs to be specified as a flex container, together with centering along its main and cross axis:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

To specify a fixed width for the child, which is called a "flex item":

```css
#content {
  flex: 0 0 120px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2woqsef1/1/

To shrink-wrap the content, it is even simpler: just remove the `flex: ...` line from the flex item, and it is automatically shrink-wrapped.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2woqsef1/2/

The examples above have been tested on major browsers including MS Edge and Internet Explorer 11.

One technical note if you need to customize it: inside of the flex item, since this flex item is not a flex container itself, the old non-flexbox way of CSS works as expected.  However, if you add an additional flex item to the current flex container, the two flex items will be horizontally placed. To make them vertically placed, add the `flex-direction: column;` to the flex container.  This is how it works between a flex container and its **immediate** child elements.

There is an alternative method of doing the centering: by not specifying `center` for the distribution on the main and cross axis for the flex container, but instead specify `margin: auto` on the flex item to take up all extra space in all four directions, and the evenly distributed margins will make the flex item centered in all directions. This works except when there are multiple flex items. Also, this technique works on MS Edge but not on Internet Explorer 11.

---

## Update for 2016 / 2017:

It can be more commonly done with `transform`, and it works well even in older browsers such as Internet Explorer 10 and Internet Explorer 11. It can support multiple lines of text:

```css
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wb8u02kL/1/

### To shrink-wrap the width:

The solution above used a fixed width for the content area. To use a shrink-wrapped width, use

```css
position: relative;
float: left;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wb8u02kL/2/

If the support for Internet Explorer 10 is needed, then flexbox won't work and the method above and the `line-height` method would work. Otherwise, flexbox would do the job.

Comment: There's now a `display: table-cell` property for that, FYI. Using it makes the element behave like a table cell and allows `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: If you're using `font:` with these, make sure you put it ahead of `line-`height`.

Comment: it does not work in IE8, is there any other way I can make it work?

Comment: I needed to center a multi-lined independent label (div-less), and the `text-align` alone solved it (and setting the width of course). Thanks.

Comment: This might not be working as intended when the div contains <br/> elements.

Comment: What if my height in %?

Comment: with this approach text text has to be in one line, otherwise you will have second line 90px below first.

Comment: @太極者無極而生 - Why did you have to add in the solutions that I already posted in 2014? Really?

Comment: @JoshCrozier I did see `transform` came into place in other websites without seeing what you posted. Your way of using `position: absolute` isn't that flexible either, as you always have to have a `position: relative` in the outer container, or else it would be absolute relatively to the whole document and usually that's not what is wanted.

Comment: @DannyWang well, since everyone is doing things this way you SHOULD accept and continue. And hey, good luck writing another 50 lines because your garbage css is not working once you change the dimension a little. For the link i found this guy, he WORKS at google. Maybe after you go through his examples you can reach him and he can tell you how you google. Don't be a sheep, question a little. https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/

Comment: @msecilmis I thought what magic you were suggesting here. So flexbox? which is already mentioned at the end of this answer as well as some other answers (Approach2 in josh crozier 's answer below).

Comment: what if you have 2 items you want to center in a div? ie a shopping cart icon and a count icon in a button?

Comment: text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 90px;       /* The same as your div height */

No need for vertical-align: middle;

Comment: @arvindakumar good catch. I think it is only needed if you want to vertically align 2 or 3 items going across the page, and so for each of them, you need to give it the `vertical-align: middle`

Answer (score 493):

### Common techniques as of 2014:

---

- #### Approach 1 - `transform` `translateX`/`translateY`:

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/47x60k4w/) / [**Full Screen Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/47x60k4w/show)

  In [supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) (most of them), you can use `top: 50%`/`left: 50%` in combination with  `translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)` to dynamically vertically/horizontally center the element.

  ```css
  .container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  }
  ```

---

- #### Approach 2 - Flexbox method:

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yeaqrh48/) / [**Full Screen Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yeaqrh48/show)

  In [supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), set the `display` of the targeted element to `flex` and use `align-items: center` for vertical centering and `justify-content: center` for horizontal centering. Just don't forget to add vendor prefixes for additional browser support ([see example](http://jsfiddle.net/yeaqrh48/)).

  ```css
  html, body, .container {
      height: 100%;
  }
  .container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
  }
  ```

---

- #### Approach 3 - `table-cell`/`vertical-align: middle`:

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sa088kb0/) / [**Full Screen Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sa088kb0/show/)

  In some cases, you will need to ensure that the `html`/`body` element's height is set to `100%`.

  For vertical alignment, set the parent element's `width`/`height` to `100%` and add `display: table`. Then for the child element, change the `display` to `table-cell` and add `vertical-align: middle`.

  For horizontal centering, you could either add `text-align: center` to center the text and any other `inline` children elements. Alternatively, you could use `margin: 0 auto` assuming the element is `block` level.

  ```css
  html, body {
      height: 100%;
  }
  .parent {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: table;
      text-align: center;
  }
  .parent > .child {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
  }
  ```

---

- #### Approach 4 - Absolutely positioned `50%` from the top with displacement:

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2epdqL5g/) / [**Full Screen Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2epdqL5g/show)

  This approach assumes that the text has a known height - in this instance, `18px`. Just absolutely position the element `50%` from the top, relative to the parent element. Use a negative `margin-top` value that is half of the element's known height, in this case - `-9px`.

  ```css
  html, body, .container {
      height: 100%;
  }
  .container {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
  }
  .container > p {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin-top: -9px;
  }
  ```

---

- #### Approach 5 - The `line-height` method (Least flexible - not suggested):

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6onex7jf/)

  In some cases, the parent element will have a fixed height. For vertical centering, all you have to do is set a `line-height` value on the child element equal to the fixed height of the parent element.

  Though this solution will work in some cases, it's worth noting that it won't work when there are multiple lines of text - [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/6rvdxbt9/).

  ```css
  .parent {
      height: 200px;
      width: 400px;
      text-align: center;
  }
  .parent > .child {
      line-height: 200px;
  }
  ```

---

Methods 4 and 5 aren't the most reliable. Go with one of the first 3.

Comment: 2. Flexbox method is the only one which works if .containers parent is absolute. 1. method makes parent to shrink because of absolute .container and 3. method simply didnt work while .parent had absolute position.

Answer (score 102):

Using flexbox/CSS:

```html
<div class="box">
    <p>&#x0D05;</p>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
.box{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Taken from [Quick Tip: The Simplest Way To Center Elements Vertically And Horizontally](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/09/quick-tip-the-simplest-way-to-center-elements-vertically-and-horizontally/)

Comment: Careful: Won't work in IE. You'll need to add `display: -ms-flexbox; -ms-flex-align: center; -ms-flex-pack: center`.

Comment: add `text-align:center` for `inline-` elements .. such as text.

Comment: Note that flexbox now has at least partial support in IE 10 and 11, and works for 97% of users according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). I don't think browser support is an argument against it anymore.

Comment: or simplified, without a css file :
<div class="some-class" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
      some text<br>
      next line<br>
</div>

Answer (score 35):

Add the line `display: table-cell;` to your CSS content for that div.

Only table cells support the `vertical-align: middle;`, but you can give that [table-cell] definition to the div...

A live example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/tH2cc/

```css
div{
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    display: table-cell; /* This says treat this element like a table cell */
    vertical-align:middle; /* Now we can center vertically like in a TD */
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if `position` is absolute or fixed. See: http://jsfiddle.net/tH2cc/1636/

Answer (score 25):

Give this CSS class to the targeted <div>:

```css
.centered {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: red; /* Not necessary just to see the result clearly */
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">This text is centered horizontally and vertically</div>
```

Answer (score 23):

You can try very easy code for this:

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

```css
.box{
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Lorem
</div>
```

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/santoshkhalse/pen/xRmZwr

Answer (score 20):

I always use the following CSS for a container, to center its content horizontally and vertically.

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;

-webkit-box-align: center;
-moz-box-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;

-webkit-box-pack: center;
-moz-box-pack: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center;
```

See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/yp1gusn7/

Answer (score 19):

**2020 Way**

```css
.parent{ 
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `flex` property at the **parent** `div` and add the `margin:auto` property to the children items:

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    /* You can change this to `row` if you want the items side by side instead of stacked */
    flex-direction: column;
}

/* Change the `p` tag to what your items child items are */
.parent p {
    margin: auto;
}
```

You can see more options of `flex` here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 11):

### Approach 1

```css
div {
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello, World!!
</div>
```

### Approach 2

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Haec et tu ita posuisti, et verba vestra sunt. Non enim iam stirpis bonum quaeret, sed animalis. </span>
</div>
```

### Approach 3

```css
div {
  display: table;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
}
span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Add the following code in the parent div

```css
display: grid;
place-items: center;
```

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```css
# Parent
{
  display: table;
}

# Child
{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%; /* As large as its parent to center the text horizontally */
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle; /* Vertically align this element on its parent */
}
```

Comment: How exactly is this different than the other answers posted?

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="small-container">
    <span>Text centered</span>
</div>

<style>
.small-container {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border:1px green solid;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.small-container span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
</style>
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting of `-moz-transform` and `-webkit-transform` is weird. It is probably due to the [new syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter).

Answer (score 5):

```css
div {
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello, World!!
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

### [GRID](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

```css
.center {
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.center {
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box center">My text</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Adjusting line height to get the vertical alignment.

```
line-height: 90px;
```

Comment: Not going to downvote because it _can_ be a solution, however this only works if you can guarantee single-line text...

Answer (score 3):

This is really simple code that works for me! It is just one line and your text will be centered horizontally.

```css
.center-horizontally{
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<Card.Footer className="card-body-padding center-horizontally">
  <label className="support-expand-text-light">Call or email Customer Support to change</label>
</Card.Footer>
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (tested OK!):

HTML:

```html
<div class="mydiv">
    <p>Item to be centered!</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.mydiv {
    height: 100%; /* Or other */
    position: relative;
}

.mydiv p {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* To compensate own width and height */
}
```

You can choose other values than 50%. For example, 25% to center at 25% of parent.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following methods:

1. If you have a single word or one line sentence, then the following code can do the trick.

   Have a text inside a div tag and give it an id. Define the following properties for that id.

   ```css
   id-name {
     height: 90px;
     line-height: 90px;
     text-align: center;
     border: 2px dashed red;
   }
   ```

   **Note:** Make sure the line-height property is same as the height of the division.

   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyKRI.png)

   But, if the content is more than one single word or a line then this doesn’t work. Also, there will be times when you cannot specify the size of a division in px or % (when the division is really small and you want the content to be exactly in the middle).
2. To solve this issue, we can try the following combination of properties.

   ```css
   id-name {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     border: 2px dashed red;
   }
   ```

   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rhHs.png)

   These 3 lines of code sets the content exactly in the middle of a division (irrespective of the size of the display). The **"align-items: center"** helps in vertical centering while **"justify-content: center"** will make it  horizontally centered.

   **Note:** Flex does not work in all browsers. Make sure you add appropriate vendor prefixes for additional browser support.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.cell-row {display: table; width: 100%; height: 100px; background-color: lightgrey; text-align: center}
.cell {display: table-cell}
.cell-middle {vertical-align: middle}
```

```html
<div class="cell-row">
  <div class="cell cell-middle">Center</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .maindiv {
        height: 450px;
        background: #f8f8f8;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      p {
        font-size: 24px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="maindiv">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this was the best solution:

HTML:

```html
<div id="outer">
    <img src="logo.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* Bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your container

display:flex,

align-items:center,

justify-content:center,

Answer (score 0):

Apply style:

```css
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Your text would be centered irrespective of its length.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.center-stuff{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 230px; /* This should be the div height */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be the right answer. Cleanest and simplest:

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: What happens if `transform: translateY(-50%);` is not included

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div style ="text-align: center;">Center horizontal text</div>
        <div style ="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);">Center vertical text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is good clean code. Although, you could add ID to your div tags, so that you can use them later on if necessary.

Comment: did you read previous answers? can you tell what this answer add to the previous ones?

Comment: @AmirMdAmiruzzaman can you tell us what is the *cleanest* part of this code :) ... I see inline styles which is not good ... also adding ID is not a good idea too, we need Classes

Comment: **Duplicate of** Approach 1 of Josh's answer

Answer (score -1):

it's easy put into the container tag for css style :

.container{
align-items:center,
line-height:{optional}px
}

Answer (score -2):

Try the following example. I have added examples for each category: horizontal and vertical

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #horizontal
            {
                text-align: center;
            }
            #vertical
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            }
         </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div id ="horizontal">Center horizontal text</div>
         <div id ="vertical">Center vertical text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the question is about centring horizontally AND vertically also this solution is already provided before