# Center text in div?

Tags: css, padding, spacing

I have a `div` `30px` high and `500px` wide. This `div` can contain two lines of text one under the other, and is styled (padded) accordingly. But sometimes it only contains one line, and I want it to be centered. Is this possible?

Comment: Centered top to bottom, right to left, or both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS center text (horizontally and vertically) inside a div block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use in your CSS the property vertical-align in order to center it verticaly

```
div {  
    vertical-align:middle;  
}
```

if it's a size problem, please notice that 2 text lines and a padding style have great chance to have a height superior to 30px.

For example, if your font size is 12 px and your div padding is 5 px, a one text line div height will be 5px (padding-top) + 12px + 5 px (padding-bottom) = 22px < 30px so no problem,

With a 2 text lines div, it will be 5px +12px *2 (2 lines) + 5px = 34px > 30px and your div height will be automatically changed.

Try either to increase your div height (maybe 40px) or to reduce your padding.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 58):

To center horizontally, use `text-align:center`.

To center vertically, one can only use `vertical-align:middle` if there is another element in the same row that it is being aligned to.
See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WCBjN/898/).

We use an empty span with a height of 100%, and then put the content in the next element with a vertical-align:middle.

There are other techniques such as using table-cell or putting the content in an absolutely positioned element with top, bottom, left, and right all set to zero, but they all suffer from cross browser compatibility issues.

Comment: The "vertical-align: middle" in the provided example has no effect. It's the line-height of the span that is centering the text

Answer (score 25):

I believe you want the text to be vertically centered inside your div, not (only) horizontally. The only reliable way I know of doing this is using:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

on your div, and it works with any number of lines.
You can see a test here: http://jsfiddle.net/qMtZV/1/

Be sure to check browser support of this property, as it is not supported — for example — in IE7 or earlier.

**UPDATE 02/10/2016**

Five years later this technique is still valid, but I believe there are better and more solid solutions to this problem. Since [Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) support is good nowadays, you might want to do something along these lines: http://codepen.io/michelegera/pen/gPZpqE.

Comment: Note: this requires that the `<div>` is set to `position: relative;`.

Comment: @JamieBirch it should be set to `relative` or to the (default) value of `static`. It won’t center the lines when position is `absolute` or `fixed`.

Answer (score 8):

For the parent div,use following CSS:

```
style="display: flex;align-items: center;"
```

Answer (score 7):

HTML

```
<div class="outside">
  <div class="inside">
      <p>Centered Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outside { 
  position: absolute; 
  display: table; 
}

.inside {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center; 
}
```

Comment: Unlike one of the other methods, I like that this one doesnt require me to keep track of the inner & outer's height

Answer (score 5):

If you have text inside a `<div>`:

```
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
div {
    height: 256px;
    width: 256px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 256px;
}
```

The trick is to set the `line-height` equal to the `height` of the `div`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding line height helps too.

```
text-align: center;
line-height: 18px; /* for example. */
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something here, but have you tried:

```
text-align:center;
```

??

Comment: thats fine on two lines but on one lne theres too big a gap after the first line

Comment: That only centers horizontally. The question seems to imply the OP wants to center vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
div { text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked around and the

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

seems to be the most popular solution

Answer (score 0):

```
display: block;
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="header">
<div class="phone">&#9742; 052 824 134</div>
<div class="adres">&#10031; бул. Княз Борис I, No 115 - Дворец на Културата и Спорта</div>
```

using flexbox To center div

```
.header{
        background: #ff6400;
        height:100px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: flex;
        justify-content:'center';
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .phone{
        color: white; 
        font-size: 20px; 
        padding: 9px 0 0 125px;
     
    }
    .adres{
        display: inline-block;
        color: white; 
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align:'center';
    }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Add to the selector containing the text

```
margin:auto;
```