# Text inside div wont center

Tags: html, css

Problem Statement : Center alignment not happening

Relevant code:

```css
#tekst {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #EFEFEF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
}

#innhold {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  top: 18%;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="innhold">
  <div id="tekst"> text </div>
</div>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use css property `text-align: center`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center text in div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055412/center-text-in-div)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-align:center;` to center text.

```css
#tekst {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #EFEFEF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}

#innhold {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  top: 18%;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="innhold">
  <div id="tekst"> text </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "`text-align: center` you must use" is how it read in my mind.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Moved to the city I have, blend in I must.

Answer (score 1):

To fully center your text you can use flexbox:

```css
#tekst {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #EFEFEF;
  height: 30%;
}

#innhold {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  top: 18%;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="innhold">
  <div id="tekst"> text </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to add the CSS property `text-align:center;`.

Hope this helps.

```css
#tekst {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align:center;
  color: #EFEFEF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
}

#innhold {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  top: 18%;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="innhold">
  <div id="tekst"> text </div>
</div>
```