# Vertically align text within a div

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

The code below (also available as [a demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/3/)) does not position the text in the middle, as I ideally would like it to. I cannot find any way to vertically centre text in a `div`, even using the `margin-top` attribute. How can I do this?

```
<div id="column-content">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/12qzO.png">
    <strong>1234</strong>
    yet another text content that should be centered vertically
</div>
```

```
#column-content {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position:relative;
}
    
#column-content strong {
    color: #592102;
    font-size: 18px;
}

img {
    margin-top:-7px;
    vertical-align: middle;        
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block/25799339#25799339

Answer (score 760, accepted):

Andres Ilich has it right. Just in case someone misses his comment...

**A.) If you only have one line of text:**

```css
div
{
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px; /* <-- this is what you must define */
}
```

```html
<div>vertically centered text</div>
```

**B.) If you have multiple lines of text:**

```css
div
{
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
}

span
{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 18px; /* <-- adjust this */
}
```

```html
<div><span>vertically centered text vertically centered text vertically centered text vertically centered text vertically centered text vertically centered text vertically centered text vertically centered text vertically centered text vertically centered text</span></div>
```

Comment: The multiple line solution does not work if you use XHTML transitional as DOCTYPE.

Comment: I had to add  text-align:center; to the parent div too. Otherwise when the text took only one line, the span would take less than 100% of the div and be left justified.

Comment: Works nice apart from not honouring word-wrap: break-word, which is broken in this case.

Comment: If you don't want to set line-height anyways - you can simply use `line-height: initial;` or........................ `line-height: normal;` :)

Comment: So this answer is just: "Measure how many pixels gets the text close enough and hard-code that"?

Comment: The snippet didn't work for me.

Answer (score 489):

Create a container for your text content, a `span` perhaps.

```css
#column-content {
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* for visual purposes */
#column-content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="column-content">

  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WxW4B.png">
  <span><strong>1234</strong>
    yet another text content that should be centered vertically</span>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/5/)

Comment: Can you explain why, when a `height` property is specified for either the `span` or the span's parent element, the `vertical-align` property does not work? Using your demo specifically, I added a `height` property to the parent element to see if the `span` would still vertically align itself, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Josh that is due to `line-height`. If you add `height` to an element where exactly does the text inside of it lie? That is, if you have a block of text that is `font-size: 10px` (a theoretical `height:10px`) inside a container that is `60px` where exactly is the text going to end up? Most surely at the top of the container, because the text can only position itself where the text flows, inside a `height:10px` space. But you can overcome that by using a `line-height` value the same height as the container, this way the text will take in the `vertical-align` property and align itself properly.

Comment: @Josh demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/37/ .. added a height of 100px to the container and also a line-height of 100px to the span tag.

Comment: This does not work with position fixed.

Comment: I'm affraid it's not working: http://jsfiddle.net/jA53e/

Comment: This only reason that jsfiddle demo "works" is the img has `vertical-align: middle;` set. Set a fixed height on the container and it does not center vertically: http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/5/

Comment: I thought `vertical-align` doesn't work on `inline-block` elements.

Comment: It seems not working in chrome.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer ? just give #column-content a height of say 300px, and you will see it does not vertically align neither the image, nor the text. Due to the small height of your demo, it gives the illusion it is working. NON ANSWER.

Comment: Does this work with `position: fixed`? My span is the exact same, but the vertical align doesn't work with my div: `<div id="leftmargin" style="position: fixed; left: 0; width: 5%; height:100%; display: inline-block; background-color: #3E484E; font-size: 48px;">`

Comment: The demo is not working. The text is aligned to the top of the image.

Answer (score 316):

**Update April 10, 2016**

Flexboxes should now be used to vertically (or even  horizontally) align items.

```css
body {
    height: 150px;
    border: 5px solid cyan; 
    font-size: 50px;
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* Vertical center alignment */
    justify-content: center; /* Horizontal center alignment */
}
```

```html
Middle
```

A good guide to flexbox can be read on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Thanks Ben (from comments) for pointing it out. I didn't have time to update.

---

A good guy named Mahendra posted a very working solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629561/css-vertical-align-middle-not-working).

The following class should make the element horizontally and vertically centered to its parent.

```
.absolute-center {

    /* Internet Explorer 10 */
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;

    /* Firefox */
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;

    /* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;

    /* W3C */
    display: box;
    box-pack: center;
    box-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Not anymore, the spec has changed and most of the above is now deprecated. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280040/css3-flexbox-display-box-vs-flexbox-vs-flex] The logic of using flexbox however is sound, something like: ```display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;```

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 67):

The accepted answer doesn't work for multi-line text.

I updated the JSfiddle [to show CSS multiline text vertical align](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/2321/) as explained [here](http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/):

```css
#column-content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}

div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="column-content">
  <div>yet another text content that should be centered vertically</div>
</div>
```

It also works with `<br />` in "yet another..."

Comment: i think the table cell should be on the wrapper, and secondly if wrapper has position absolute it stops working

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div><span>Text</span></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height: 100px;
}

span {
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

This is simply supposed to work:

```
#column-content {
        --------
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

I tried it on your demo.

Comment: This should be the same as `margin:auto 0` where the first value ('auto') is for top and bottom margin and the second value (the 0) is for the left and right margin.

Comment: You are right! but in this way it's more clear for beginners, and your comment makes it wiser. thanks!

Comment: This works only with a parent element using either `display:flex` or `display:grid` or `display:inline-table` or `display:inline-grid`. Doesn't work in older browsers

Comment: nice solution, well done

Answer (score 18):

To make Omar's (or Mahendra's) solution even more universal, the block of code relative to Firefox should be replaced by the following:

```
/* Firefox */
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

The problem with Omar's code, otherwise operative, arises when you want to center the box in the screen or in its immediate ancestor. This centering is done either by setting its position to

`position: relative;` or `position:static;` (not with position:absolute nor fixed).

And then *margin: auto;* or *margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;*

Under this box center aligning environment, Omar's suggestion does not work. It doesn't work either in Internet Explorer 8 (yet 7.7% market share). So for Internet Explorer 8 (and other browsers), a workaround as seen in other above solutions should be considered.

Comment: This worked for me thanks including when I use float:left: to create  a row of buttons.  The complexity of explaining why it works hints at the general difficulty with CSS: You can not achieve the simple effect of centering text inside a DIV  with any single directive.  You have to combine multiple attributes, and how they  work in combination with other attributes is difficult to foresee without trying them out in different contexts including with different browsers.

Answer (score 7):

Add a vertical align to the CSS content `#column-content strong` too:

```
#column-content strong {
    ...
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also see your [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/8/).

=== UPDATE ===

With a span around the other text and another vertical align:

HTML:

```
... <span>yet another text content that should be centered vertically</span> ...
```

CSS:

```
#column-content span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also see the [next example](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/10/).

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest way to do it if you need multiple lines. Wrap you `span`'d text in another `span` and specify its height with `line-height`. The trick to multiple lines is resetting the inner `span`'s `line-height`.

```html
<span class="textvalignmiddle"><span>YOUR TEXT HERE</span></span>
```

```css
.textvalignmiddle {
    line-height: /* Set height */;
}

.textvalignmiddle > span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1em; /* Set line height back to normal */
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QAwpm/1/)

Of course the outer `span` could be a `div` or what have you.

Answer (score -2):

I know it’s totally stupid and you normally really shouldn’t use tables when not creating tables, but:

Table cells can align multiple lines of text vertically centered and even do this by default. So a solution which works quite fine could be something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <table class="textalignmiddle">
    <tr>
      <td>lorem ipsum ...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS (make the table item always fit to the box div):

```
.box {
  /* For example */
  height: 300px;
}

.textalignmiddle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

See here:
http://www.cssdesk.com/LzpeV