# Vertically center <span> text which is beside a much larger <span>, both inside a <div>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically center some text in a `<span>` element, in relation to a much larger `<span>` that is a sibling of the first one. Both are children of a containing parent `<div>` element.

#### HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="previewLabel">Preview:</span>
    <span class="previewText">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</span>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.previewLabel {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.previewText {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 64px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5chXG/

As you can see, I already tried the `vertical-align` trick (with the `line-height` defined) that is described in [this Q&A ("Text vertical align in a div")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9249359/346561) but it doesn't seem to work. I think the difference is that I can't use a static `line-height` value.

I can't use a `px` value for the `line-height` property because the `.previewText` span can change sizes dynamically. In the real code, there are controls on the page to change the font properties and JavaScript will adjust the CSS of the `.previewText` while you change things.

#### My Question:

How can make the "Preview:" text (`.previewLabel`) `<span>` be vertically aligned in the middle of the parent `<div>` element?

#### Edit / Clarification

I would like *ALL* of the text to behave as a single line of text normally would.

- Wrapping should cause the big text to flow under the smaller text.
- The smaller text should only be vertically aligned within the height of a single line of larger text, not multiple lines

Here is a visualization of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: You mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5chXG/1/?

Comment: @j08691 Sort of, that makes it look like 2 different elements though. I wanted it to look like one continuous line. So the big text would still wrap under the little text and the little text would only be vertically aligned to the middle of 1 line of big text. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: Change `vertical-align: middle` to `vertical-align: baseline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `vertical-align:middle` to both `.previewLabel` and `.previewText` will work just fine.

And here is a fiddle for proof: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/5chXG/4/

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't exactly what I am looking for. Sorry if I was not clear in the question. I want all of the text to flow like 1 line. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888515/vertically-center-span-text-which-is-beside-a-much-larger-span-both-inside#comment33144820_21888515).

Comment: Then you should just add `vertical-align:middle` to both of them, doesn't that work for you?

Comment: Indeed, adding `vertical-align:middle` to both spans seems to do the trick! Your previous version of the answer/fiddle didn't look right to me so I thought it was wrong, sorry. Thanks!

Comment: Also, could you explain *why* this works? I wouldn't expect to need to vertically align the element which is the full height of the container. Why is that making a difference?

Comment: In plain words, `vertical-align` describes the way that `inline-elements` will be vertical aligned with each other if put side by side. It has nothing to do with their parent element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the left one-line text to align to the first line of multi-line text on the right, you need to use `vertical-align: baseline` instead of `vertical-align: middle` along with `display: table-cell`. `.previewLabel` doesn't need a set line-height.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5chXG/3/)**

```
.previewLabel {
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

span {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Your demo is making the text in the "previewText `<span>`act as if it isn't the same line of text as the label. I would like it to act as though it is a single line of text. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888515/vertically-center-span-text-which-is-beside-a-much-larger-span-both-inside#comment33144820_21888515).

Comment: Also, in my browser (Firefox) the "Preview:" text is still not vertically aligned in the middle; it still appears at the bottom of the line.

Comment: Yeah, from your explanation I thought you wanted it aligned to the bottom of the first line. That image you included would have helped me better understand exactly what you were looking for. I'm glad you were able to get a helpful answer.