# Vertically aligning a text inside a CSS box

Tags: css, html

I wanted to make my text that is inside my CSS box vertically aligned on the middle. I tried valign="middle" on the div but it didn't work.
CSS:

```
        #leadboard
    {
        width: 1300px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #dedede;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="leadboard" align="center">
        <h1>Text Here</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: for h1 give line-height:100px;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text vertical align in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249359/text-vertical-align-in-a-div)

Comment: Well, I actually did a lot of search and I didn't find anything for what I am asking right now.

Answer (score 1):

If your text is one line -

```
#leadboard {
    line-height: 100px; /* Equal to height */
}
```

If your text is several lines -

```
#leadboard {
    display: table;
}
#leadboard h1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
#leadboard
{
    width: 1300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #dedede;
    display: table;
}
#leadboard h1
{
    display: table-cell;    
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

or

```
#leadboard
{
    width: 1300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #dedede;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me what display: table-cell does?

Comment: It's the property to display like a table cell and replace the property valign which is not supported in HTML5.