# How to vertically align text in an inline-block td?

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, css

I have a table with one row full of tds. I made them display: inline-block so that they would wrap with the page. I can't seem to make the text inside them vertical-align: middle. How would I accomplish this? Or is display: inline-block not the way to go? Thanks.

**EDIT**
Here is the code. Sorry I'm new to posting.

```
<div>
    <table class="disk-size-table center">
        <tr class="disk-size-row">

            <!-- <td class="disk-size-td draggable" data-disk-size="500">
                    500 GB <!-- I want the 500GB to be vertical align middle
                 </td> -->

        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

.disk-size-table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.disk-size-td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

table.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I dynamically generate tds that look like the commented one. I want them to show up vertically aligned middle. Let me know if I need to post anything else.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To write a better question and increase your chances of receiving answers, please include your relevant code in the question.

Comment: you could try text-align: center; or follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249359/is-it-possible-to-vertically-align-text-within-a-div

Comment: Try to explain what you are trying to achieve.   Using `td` elements implies that you want all the elements to have the same height.  But changing the display type to inline-block will cause each cell to have a shrink to fit height/width.  Without any additional information, it is hard to propose a solution.  Usually with these questions, as soon as an answer is posted, new requirements come out, so please, elaborate!

Comment: I ended up adding line-height equal to the height.

Comment: @SkeetsMcCoy `line-height` only works if you don't have multiple lines of text. Simply remove your fixed height for `.disk-size-td` (see my answer below) and it should work with multiple lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Bwej/)

Only change made is in **CSS**

```
.disk-size-td {
    .....
     display: table-cell; // Add this
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If having `display: inline-block` isn't a requirement for another piece of you project, you can simply change to `display: float` which will give you the style you desire.  There are a few functional differences you should look out for if you do do this which can be better understood from this explanation of the difference betweent the two: http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html .

Comment: Float did not work either. It still did not vertical align middle.

Comment: `display: float` doesn't exist in CSS, you probably meant `float: left / right`

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the td's as table-cells, you can use this:

```
<style>
td { display: table-cell; border: 1px solid red; max-width: 250px; }

.content, .vcenter { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
.content { border: 1px solid green; }
.vcenter { height: 100%; width: 0; }
</style>

<table><tr>
<td>
    <div class="content">
        500 GB
    </div><div class="vcenter"></div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="content">
        asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf 
    </div><div class="vcenter"></div>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

The "vcenter" div expands to the height of the cell, making the line that high inside the cell. Then the "content" div can use vertical-align:middle to align itself vertically on the line within the cell.

If you change the td's into inline-blocks, using vertical-align:middle on the cells should make the cells align on the vertical center of the line:

```
<style>
td { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid red; max-width: 250px; }

.content { border: 1px solid green; }

</style>

<table><tr>
<td>
    <div class="content">
        500 GB
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="content">
        asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf 
    </div>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

But if the td's need to go on multiple lines, then there is no point in using tables, and it's easier to use div's only.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align: middle` works both with `display: table-cell` in CSS / `<td>` in HTML and `display: inline-block;`.

Since you are already using `<table>` for your markup you don't need to use `display: inline-block;` anymore.

To vertically align your `<td>` simply remove your fixed `height: 70px;` and `display: inline-block;` from `.disk-size-td {}`. Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbfz3/). If all your items have a fixed height there is nothing to align vertically :)

You may want to add some `padding: 10px 0;` (or whatever padding you want) to your `<td>` as well.