# css vertical align within float and height 100%

Tags: css, css-float, height, vertical-alignment

ive got some problem with my css styles:
I have different groups ( `<div>`'s ) that have subgroups displayed in ONE colum
or MULTIPLE ( max. 3) colums.

The problem i have is, that my `vertical-align` wont work within float elements with an 100% height.

within the subgroups: ST200 | Überblick... | EN DE should be displayed with
 `vertical-align: middle`

Maybe someone could help me.
complete code posted on jfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ZAa33/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution to my Question that works pretty nice ;)

i just needed to set:

```
.kurs {
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    background-color: #c5c5c5;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    ! display: -webkit-flex; <- remove
    ! display: -moz-box;     <- remove
    align-items: center;     <- add
    justify-content: center; <- add
}
```

The updated fiddle ;) 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZAa33/9/

Answer (score 0):

Vertical-Align Property works with only inline and inline-block elements. if you float any element, by default that element display property value is changed to block. In your case that is why vertical-alignment is not working on floated element. one solution for your problem is use inline.

```
[Inline-block demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mostwanted_cJ/W8nf8)
```

Your JSFiddle is edited.
change all of your span to div and apply display:inline-block and vertical-align:middle

[Inline-block demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h7CNu/1/)

Comment: I tried it, but it wont work and i guess its because of my wrapper that has display: flex but i dont know,

Comment: another problem is, that your divs are vertical-aligned and i need to have them 100% and just the text inside at middle i tryed to use `<p>` for it but wont work either

Comment: i have fixed you code and added link at the bottom. check that.

Comment: dont see the result i like but thx so far ;) i did an easier way now and used a table within my `kurs`

Answer (score 0):

Andres's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249359/is-it-possible-to-vertically-align-text-within-a-div#comment12899155_9249396) seems to address your problem: the `line-height` of the text is confining it to a smaller area than its container div.

To test, I changed the `line-height` property on `.kursid` to `35px`, and the ST200 was successfully centered vertically, but only for those divs that had heights of 35px. For a more general solution, you could redesign your code to allow `line-height` and `height` to be set explicitly equal on all divs with text you want centered vertically, or you could see the other answers to that question for other options.

Comment: those divs will be filled by DB entries as it is ready, so i cant do a fixed height :/ thats why i posted `height 100%` at the topic