# CSS table-cell size - conterintuitive behaviour

Tags: html, css

Have a look to the following two images:

Enabling or disabling the table-cell attribute discards the information about width and height. Actually I've them already disabled by the browser, but reenabling them changes nothing.

Using `display:table-cell` is the only way to use `vertical-align` to center some text inside the container.

But then it becomes hard to play with the width of the yellow div element. Why? 
(also I wonder.. if some property get uneffective for some element when some others are enabled the browser could mark them with a different color or strikeout them.. Or there would be some cons?)

[image][image]

```css
.grey-footer-background {
  background-color: #a8a7a5;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
  padding-top: 8px;
  display: table;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.gold_button {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: solid 1px #262626;
  width: 80%;
  height: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="grey-footer-background">
  <div class="gold_button"><span>Email</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display:table-cell` means that the `div` will take up the full width of the parent with either `display:table-row` or `display:table` unless shared with other "cells" and then the width will be split between them.  You could make your `.gold_button` the table and the `span` the table-cell instead

```css
.grey-footer-background {
    background-color: #a8a7a5;
    border-bottom: 1px black solid;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.gold_button {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: solid 1px #262626;
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:gold;
}
.gold_button span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grey-footer-background">
  <div class="gold_button">
    <span>Email</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/oqyef0uv/1)

Answer (score 1):

[Is this what you're looking for? (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/hs786fwn/)

Adding:

```
line-height: desired height
```

should do it.

Comment: This is a very nice workaround.. probably the best one, but it require to know the height of the parent element.. For me W3C should add another vertical-align to change the alignment of elements like in a table-cell way. However +1