# Vertically centering content within a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically center some h2 text within a div using `display:table-cell` combined with `vertical-align: middle`.

However, this is not working seemingly because the div I'm trying to center the content in is the child of another div.

Here is my CSS and HTML:

```css
.productList {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1120px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.hoverbase1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
.hoverbase1 a br {
  display: none;
}
.hoverbase1 img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
.hovertop1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  opacity: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.hoverbase1 a:hover + .hovertop1,
.hovertop1:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='productList'>
  <div class='hoverbase1'>
    <a href='http://kingfisher.org.au/library-shelving'>
      <img src="http://kingfisher.org.au/pic/library_shelving.jpg" />
    </a>
    <div class='hovertop1'>
      <a href='http://kingfisher.org.au/library-shelving'>
        <h3>Library Shelving</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also available as [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66ondoyo/).

Comment: This question has been [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css) [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249359/is-it-possible-to-vertically-align-text-within-a-div?lq=1) [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers?rq=1). At least one of them could answer yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have prepared this example with `display: inline-block`, instead of table-cell, so they can wrap and I removed all unneeded HTML markup.

## Main CSS Properties

- The text is centered using a pseudo element, `.product:before`. Essentially this element forces the inline text to vertically align in the middle. If you need this to work in IE6 - 7, it can be replaced with a div.
- The text is given 0 opacity until `.product` is hovered.
- The image is `position: absolute` and will position itself in relation with it's `position: relative` parent. This is needed to pull it out of the flow in order to align the text.
- The transitions smooth out the opacity changes. `.product` is given a white border so that it can transition to a black border when hovered.

**Note:** Currently there is no fallback for browsers which don't support `opacity`, namely IE6 and 7. This can be achieved, if needed, with `display: none` in an IE 6 / 7 conditional stylesheet.

## 2 Examples

"Show code snippet" and run it.

### We don't need no silly div

The class `.product` is given to the `<a>` element and the entire box is a link.

```
<a class="product" href="href='http://kingfisher.org.au/library-shelving">
  <img src="http://kingfisher.org.au/pic/library_shelving.jpg" />
  <h2>Library Shelving</h2> 
</a>
```

```css
.product {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px #FFF;
  transition: border 1s;
  text-align: center;
}
.product:before {
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.product img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.product:hover {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
.product:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
}
.product h2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  font-weight: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.product:hover h2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
.product {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="product" href="href='http://kingfisher.org.au/library-shelving">
  <img src="http://kingfisher.org.au/pic/library_shelving.jpg" />
  <h2>Library Shelving</h2> 
</a>
```

### With a div - "I don't want them clicking just anywhere!"

- The class `.product` is given to a div that contains the image and text. Only the text is a link.
- The `<a>` is position relative so it can be given `z-index: 2` to ensure that it is clickable. This is mainly for IE8 and 9.
- The image is given `z-index: 1` so that it positions itself underneath the `<a>`

```
<div class="product">
  <img src="http://kingfisher.org.au/pic/library_shelving.jpg" />
  <a href="href='http://kingfisher.org.au/library-shelving">
    Library Shelving
  </a>
</div>
```

```css
.product {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px #FFF;
  transition: border 1s;
}
.product:before {
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.product img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}
.product:hover {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
.product:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
}
.product a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}
.product:hover a {
  opacity: 1;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <img src="http://kingfisher.org.au/pic/library_shelving.jpg" />
  <a href="href='http://kingfisher.org.au/library-shelving">
    Library Shelving
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You now have two examples to choose from :)

Answer (score 0):

With the `table-cell` it makes vertical center and as usual, `text-align:center` does horizontal center.

```
.hovertop1 a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Try with this.

Comment: While [one line answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266954/one-line-answers) and snippet-only are acceptable, they often result in the answer being routed to the Review Queue (*q.v.*). In addition, sometimes they are not well received by the community. Its usually a good idea to provide a brief explanation that explains how the answer solves the problem.

Comment: @jww I'm sorry, I didnt get much time to write the answer just gave the idea, I'll update now.

Comment: See [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) on Meta...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position:relative;` to the div containing the `<h2>` then add this to the `<h2>` element:

```
position:absolute;
top: 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. I've made it incredibly simple. The key is setting `line-height` on the parent and `vertical-align` on the child (NOT THE PARENT!). `vertical-align` only works within the space of a line. Even if you have a div with `height:300px;` The default line-height will be the `font-size` so you need to set it manually.

http://jsfiddle.net/y6mx14pz/

```
div{
    text-align:center;
    line-height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

h1{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```