# name the css property, please. some font "baseline alignment". what is it?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

this css in my view should stretch the "x" over the whole input content.

```
input{
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:0;  
}
```

Instead, there appears to be some font inherited property going on that pushes the "x" down.

I have no idea what that is. Can you help?

I've made a jsfiddle should you want play about with it.
http://jsfiddle.net/uc4z20yb/
[image: IMG]

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to vertically align text within a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249359/is-it-possible-to-vertically-align-text-within-a-div)

Comment: Button styles are highly OS-specific. You might want to consider [resetting them](http://fvsch.com/code/button-css/test.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically Align text in a Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Comment: What happens when you give that a `border: none;`? haha

Comment: @Terry tried. doesn't do. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/uc4z20yb/2/)

Comment: Don't forget about the font and the font-size. If you use a capital X in a common font it will look more in the middle than a non-capital x. Played a bit with the values and here's a comparison between `x` and `X`. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9awj8m9m/)

Comment: It's not CSS. What's pushing the X down is a property of the OS theme.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know it`s not the cleanest solution but you can do this.

```
<button><span>X</span></button>
```

Then in css:

```
button{
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
 padding:0;
 font-weight:20px;
 line-height:20px;
 position:relative;
}

button span{
 position:relative;
 top:-5px;
}
```

I do not know if you are trying to create a checkbox or the above is just a example, but if you are trying to create a checkbox, there are better ways to do it.

Answer (score -1):

**New answer:**
Ah, I see what you are trying to do here.

In this example I used `vertical-align` set to baseline with `line-height`.

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/4fy9k6t9/1/

Also. If you are using the small 'x' it will always be a bit down off the center, because the size of the lette ris determined by it's capital letter height: 'X', so use X. I assume it's a close button.

If you MUST use small 'x' your best bet is `padding-bottom: 2px` or so.

Comment: vertical-align applies to input elements?

Comment: Applies to just about anything.

Comment: thanks @Alexus, but that's not quite what I am after. you are compensating that unknown property that pushed down by x by adding x to padding-bottom (btw, still not vertically aligned if you look carefully). I would like to know what is pushing the text down and reset it.