# Is it possible to put another div or HTML element replacing "Hello World" text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
 <body onload="myfunction('target')"><div id="target"> "Hello World" </div></body>
```

Is It Possible To Put Another Div Or HTML Element Replacing "Hello World" Text?
  Hello World is a Left To Right Marquee Text

```
<script language="javascript">
  function myfunction(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    var textnode = element.childNodes[0];
    var text = textnode.data;

    setInterval(function() {
      text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
      textnode.data = text;
    }, 400)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: so you want to replace what's inside your `div #target` with some other HTML tag ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to make this code do? What does it do instead?

Comment: Please be clear about what it is you want to achieve here.

Comment: Looks like on load it will load Hello World. Is it you are intending to replace div on user action like click or hover?

Comment: Do you want to change the text with any HTML elements? 
If you are using jQuery you cab simply do it by $("#target").html("<p>ANY HTML CONTENTS</p>");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to vertically align text within a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249359/is-it-possible-to-vertically-align-text-within-a-div)

Comment: Please do not deface your post.

Comment: @Mahfuz how is that even related? Did you read that question or even your own?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to replace the text that is in the `innerHTML`/`innerText` querying the `HTML element` and simply setting it's `innerHTML`/`innerText` to the new value will suffice.

Example:
    const myElement = document.getElementByTagName('h1')
    myElement[0].innerHTML = 'new value'

Comment: The code is already rewriting the text inside the element, (try the "run code snippet" in the question)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change html inside div and change to another div or text or any html 
you can do like this you don't need to replace

```
$('#target').html('<div class="col-md-2"></div>');
```

and if you want to replace then you can do like this

```
$('#target').html().replace("hello",'<div class="col-md-2"></div>');
```

Comment: `.replace()` creates a new string, it will not write the new content to the element

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` should do the trick, if you are trying to add html elements:

Here is the working example of your code snippet:

https://codebrace.com/editor/b15cd15b3

Example:

```
...
element.innerHTML = "<span style='color: red; background-color:yellow;'>" + text + "</span>";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

html code

```
<body onload="myfunction()">
  <div id="target"> Hello World </div>
</body>
```

javascript code

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("target").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("Hello World", "testing");
    document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = res;
}

myFunction();
```

Replacing the `helloworld` html to `testing` html using `onload` function.