# my vertical text align middle did not work

Tags: html, css

There is something wrong with my code. I need to vertically center the text in the middle of each box.

```
#navcontainer {
    padding: 0 5 20px 10px;
}
ul#navlist {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul#navlist a {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height:20px vertical-align: middle;
}
ul#navlist, ul#navlist ul, ul#navlist li {
    margin: 0 8px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 12px #aaa;
}
ul#navlist li {
    float: left;
}
ul#navlist li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #EF634A;
    //padding:10px;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border: 1px #ffffff outset;
    height: 40px;
}
ul#navlist li a:hover {
    color: #ffff00;
    background-color: #003366;
}
ul#navlist li a:active {
    color: #cccccc;
    background-color: #003366;
    border: 1px #ffffff inset;
}
ul#subnavlist {
    display: none;
}
ul#subnavlist li {
    float: none;
}
ul#subnavlist li a {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 20px;
}
ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist {
    display: block;
    //display: inline-block;
    //display: table-cell;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist li a {
    display: block;
    width : 260;
    height : 100;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
}
ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist li a:before {
    content:" >> ";
}
```

and

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=1">PROGRAMME EUROPÉEN DE LUTTE <br/>CONTRE LE TRUCAGE DE MATCHS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=2">ACTUALITÉS SPORTIVES</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=3">COMMUNIQUÉS</a>
        </li>
        <li id="active"><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=4" id="current">THEMATIQUES</a> 
            <ul id="subnavlist">
                <li id="subactive"><a href="#" id="subcurrent">Lutte contre la corruption</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=4&id=1">Evènements sportifs </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=4&id=2">Bonne gouvernance du sport</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=4&id=3">Economie du sport</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=4&id=4">Lutte contre le dopage</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=4&id=5">Lutte pour l'intégrité dans le sport</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/R8S7q/

Comment: Please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Do you mean vertical-align: middle; ? center vertically or horizontally?

Comment: text-align:center will work

Comment: i am pretty sure he wanted vertical align because the boxes are not big enough for horizontal align

Comment: // does not count as a comment in css...only /**/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Use line-height on li to center and then revert it to normal on anchor (to deal with multiline text)

**2)** Place padding / hover classes on li element instead on anchor.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/R8S7q/6/)**

```
   ul#navlist li
   {
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    background-color: #EF634A;
   }
   ul#navlist > li
   {
    height:62px; /* <----  */
    line-height:62px; /* <----  */
   }
    ul#navlist li:hover
    {
        color: #ffff00;
        background-color: #003366;
    }
    ul#navlist a
    {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height:normal; /* <----  */
    vertical-align: middle; /* <----  */
    }
```

Comment: ok! the text is really in the middle. The only problem is with the submenu. The height for each line is to high

Comment: very good! How can I reduce the shadow in the submenu blog (see the right side) Thanks!

Comment: Ok! It is good. I am looking to put this in a width of 730px. Which part can I adapt here?

Comment: In #navcontainer class. Please, if you have further questions ask them in a new question. I have already answered your initial question

Comment: To mark as answer click on the check icon next to the question score...to upvote click on the up arrow

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all your links are `display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;` so they fill the parent element. Make sure the parent elements also have `width: 100%; height: 100%;` so they expand properly.

To center the text itself, see this question: [CSS Center text (Horizontal and Vertical) inside a DIV block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block)

Comment: @LoganMurphy: Makes centering so much more simple, yes.