# How do I get text to go in the middle of a div?

Tags: html, css

Why won't the text in the footer go at middle height in the div? Not really had anyone explain how to properly make a text sit in the middle (height-wise) of a div, hopefully this will also fix the white spacing at the bottom of the page as I believe that is caused by the text being pushed down

**HTML**

```
<div class="yellowfooterbackground">
    <div class="yellowfootercontent">
        <div class="yellowfootercontentleft">
            <p>IPS Fire & Security is a trading name of IPS Facilities - <u><a href="Terms-And-Conditions.html">Terms & Conditions</a></u></p>
        </div>
        <div class="yellowfootercontentright">
            <p> Web Design & SEO by Raven </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.yellowfootercontent {
    height: 30px;
    width: 950px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;  
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}

.yellowfootercontentleft {
    height: 30px;
    width: 475px;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

.yellowfootercontentright {
    height: 30px;
    width: 475px;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of the code above: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJS4m/)

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use line-height:

```
.yellowfootercontent {
  height: 30px;
  width: 950px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 5px;
}
```

**References**

[line-height](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#line-height)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.yellowfootercontentright {
 height: auto;
 width: 475px;
 margin-right: 20%;
 margin-left: 20%;
 line-height: 4px;
 }
```

The line height will resolve the height issue.

Answer (score 0):

.yellowfottercontent, text-align you have applied as "**left**", it should be center to get the text to center.

```
.yellowfootercontentleft {
height: 30px;
width: 475px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
 }
```

one more thing, it too depends on height you will give to the div ,for example check this fiddle

[text at center](http://jsfiddle.net/Manjuboyz/vJS4m/5/)

here height is 50px, and margin is 10px that means, margin surrounds with 10px of space which helps in text to be center of the div

let me know