# Center div vertically and horizontally without defined height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display a div in the centre of my page without having to define a set height for the element so that the height fits the content of the page dynamically. Is this possible? I am open to using JS/jQuery solutions as long as they have graceful fallbacks but I would prefer pure CSS solution.

Here is my current code, it will centre the div, but I have to include a height.

HTML

```
    <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, minim molestie argumentum est at, 
pri legere torquatos instructior ex. Vis id odio atomorum oportere, quem modo fabellas sit 
at, dicat semper est ne. Apeirian detraxit pri eu. No solum accusam has. Ius ne harum mundi 
clita, eu pro tation audiam.
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.card {
    background-color: #1d1d1d; /* IE fallback */
    background-color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.95);
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;   
    padding: 30px 35px;
    outline: 2px solid #3B3A37;
    outline-offset: -9px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 350px;
    /*margin: 0 auto;*/
}
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/0rfxnyrd/)

This question is different from previous topics because of the time it has been asked, the similar question that it has been compared to is dated from 2011 in which a lot has changed and new functions have been added to CSS3 that could fulfil the requirement better.

Comment: you need center align horizontally, or vertically also??

Comment: I don't see it.  It works in your fiddle when you take off the height.

Comment: Try the CSS approaches covered in [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block/25799339#25799339). No JS needed - the methods work for dynamic dimensions.

Comment: @AshishBalchandani both

Comment: @bowheart It will make the content resize to the whole screen which I dont want, it should fit the content.

Answer (score 8):

You could do it by set `top:50%;` and `transform: translateY(-50%);` to `.card`

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0rfxnyrd/8/) or [Full Screen View](http://jsfiddle.net/0rfxnyrd/8/show/)

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
.card {
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
    /* IE fallback */
    background-color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.95);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 30px 35px;
    outline: 2px solid #3B3A37;
    outline-offset: -9px;
    width: 320px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

For more info:

> - [W3.ORG - CSS Transforms Module Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/)
> - [Mozilla MDN - CSS Transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Comment: I have come across an article online which describes a bug with this issue (look at the update) http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Comment: @Imran check this out if you're not using half pixel transform then it works just fine - http://martinkool.com/post/27618832225/beware-of-half-pixels-in-css and my solution doesn't use half pixel its `transform: translateY(-50%);`, so there's no need to worry! :)

Comment: I am experiencing the blur effect on some of my pages.

Comment: @Imran and apply the `transform-style: preserve-3d;` didn't solved your problem and could you share a working demo?

Comment: http://shoutkey.com/build

Answer (score 4):

If you want a CSS only solution without specifying height:

- You can use [css3 flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes):

  ```
  body {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
  }
  ```

  [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0rfxnyrd/9/)
- Or you can use the translate technique:

  ```
  .card {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    /* other styles */
  }
  ```

  [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0rfxnyrd/10/)

browser support:

- flexbox  @[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)
- transform  @[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

*Side note: You might need js fallbacks if you want to support old browsers*

Comment: your flexbox solution is really good. +0001 :)

Comment: @TJ The translate technique causes the blur effect has mentioned on the other answer.

Comment: @Imran i don't see any blur effect in the fiddle shared above...