# Center a div on HTML relatively

Tags: html, css

I have the following div with list content. How to center it on an HTML page relative taking the size of the content of the div into consideration?

HTML

```
    <div id="container">
        <dl>
            <dt>Item 1</dt>
            <dt>Item 2</dt>
            <dt>Item 3</dt>
            <dt>Item 4</dt>
        </dl>
    </div>
```

I have the following css which works fine to position the div horizontally but it doesn't work for vertical center position:

```
    div {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        width: 50%;
        left: 25%;
        top: 50%;
        border-width: 4px;
        border-style: groove;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Since you're using width: 50% it's not relative to the size of the content, right?

Comment: Yes you are right. transform: translateY(-50%); works for vertical center position. How to achieve the same effect horizontally? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by set `transform: translateY(-50%);` to `div`.

**JSfiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ygnbgL7k/4/)**

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <dl>
            <dt>Item 1</dt>
            <dt>Item 2</dt>
            <dt>Item 3</dt>
            <dt>Item 4</dt>
        </dl>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    top: 50%;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: groove;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Set `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to center the `div` horizontally and vertically.

**JSfiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ygnbgL7k/12/)**

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: groove;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: It works. How to achieve the same effect horizontally? Thanks.

Comment: @KokHowTeh but Its center even if you remove the width - http://jsfiddle.net/ygnbgL7k/14/

Comment: @KokHowTeh I answered the question as per your HTML and CSS codes and if you have different code then please provide me and look at my previous answer that may also help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834692/center-div-vertically-and-horizontally-without-defined-height/25834864#25834864 and you could also use display table method like that answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832874/how-to-center-horizontally-and-vertically-a-select-box/25832999#25832999

Comment: @Melody, I don't have a different code. The div appears to occupy the left 50% left of the page horizontally which is not what I want. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: @Melody, it works now. I missed the "left: 50%;" which was 25% orignally. Thank you!

Comment: @KokHowTeh are you using this line? - `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` - http://jsfiddle.net/ygnbgL7k/12/ and this is output - http://oi58.tinypic.com/2w65vmf.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

```
 html,body{height: 100%;}

#container {
align-items: center;
display: flex;
height: 100%;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
}
```

use vendor prefix for browser support