# CSS position: absolute - understanding how to center text inside a div box

Tags: html, css

I was trying to find out how to dynamically center a text inside a `div` box using only CSS3 and I found this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25799339/1445572

I used the "Approach 1" and it solved my problem:

```
.container {  
    position: absolute;  
    top: 50%;  
    left: 50%;  
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);  
}
```

Now I am trying to understand why this code works. I know that when you change the `position` to `absolute`, you remove the element from the normal flow and you can position it (by using `top`, `left`, ...) in relation to its containing element.

Therefore, the code:

```
.container {  
    position: absolute;  
    top: 50%;  
    left: 50%;   
}
```

positions the starting edge of text box right in the center of the `div`. Even though the text box in the center, the text itself is not centered. So we need to compensate that somehow.

QUESTION: What is `translateX(-50%)` doing exactly? More specifically, `50%` of what?

(I couldn't find an explanation of `translateX` using percentages and their meaning in this context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, `translateX()` works the same as if you had used `left` (or `right`) to change the horizontal position of the element. The only difference is that when you use `left` to change the position, the element shifts accordingly **and** affects nearby elements. But if you use `translateX` the DOM is unaware of the transformation and renders all the nearby elements as if the transformed `div` was not moved at all. So if you do not want the position of neighboring elements to be affected by the *change in the position* of a particular `div` use `translate`.

The `50%` refers to 50% of the width (when using `translateX`).