# Div won't stay auto centered

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to fix the red div to stay auto centered like this

[image: http://i.imgur.com/hq7bng9.png]

so when the pink div on the left get's bigger or smaller the red div on the right will always be center but it doesn't seem to want to stay, if anyone could help I will be most grateful, thank you very much, http://jsfiddle.net/f4woL4h2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
.informationbox {
position: relative;
width: 50%;
background-color:green;
overflow: hidden;
}
.left {
width: 50%;
float: left;
background-color: pink;
}
.right {
width: 50%;
float: right;
text-align: right;
background-color: red;
vertical-align:middle;
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="informationbox">
    <div class="left">
        Left Filler Line #1<br />Left Filler Line #2<br />Left Filler Line #3<br />Left Filler Line #4<br />Left Filler Line #5
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Right Filler
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Vertical centering is pitifully a very complicated matter in current CSS, even in CSS 3. Please google "CSS3 + vertical centering".

Comment: Can the HTML be changed at all?

Comment: One of these answers gotta work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css

Comment: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[One approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block/25799339#25799339) would be to relatively position the parent element and then absolutely position the child element `50%` from the top. Then `transform: translateY(-50%)` is used for vertical centering. This will work for dynamically varying heights, therefore it should always work.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zp2c0cvx/)

```
.informationbox {
    position: relative;
}
.right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a single div around the text in your right div, you can get it to work with this CSS:

```css
.informationbox {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    background-color:green;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:table;
}
.left {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: pink;
}
.right {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
}
.left, .right {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.right div {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="informationbox">
    <div class="left">Left Filler Line #1
        <br />Left Filler Line #2
        <br />Left Filler Line #3
        <br />Left Filler Line #4
        <br />Left Filler Line #5</div>
    <div class="right">
        <div>Right Filler</div>
    </div>
</div>
```