# How can I center text without it staying at the top it's containing element?

Tags: html, css, position, transform

I have been attempting to use `vertical-align: middle` and `text-align: center` to center the button, but it does not affect my styling at all and the button stays at the top.

I am not sure why the style is not being applied. I can use `top: 50%`, but that is not the true center depending on the amount of text the button will contain.

```css
#selectmanager-outer {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

 #selectmanager-inner {
    height: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;    
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#F5F5F5), to(#FAFAFA));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#F5F5F5, #FAFAFA);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#F5F5F5, #FAFAFA);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#F5F5F5, #FAFAFA);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#F5F5F5, #FAFAFA);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id='selectmanager-outer'>
    <div id ='selectmanager-inner'>
        <button>Very long button name to test</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Solution:** With the assistance of Akheel K M's answer with the use of position, percentages, and transforms.

```css
#selectmanager-outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

#selectmanager-inner {
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0; 
  border-radius: 30px 30px; 
  background: #F5F5F5;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5, #FAFAFA);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5, #FAFAFA);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5, #FAFAFA);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5, #FAFAFA);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F5F5F5, #FAFAFA);
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#selectmanager-inner button {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id='selectmanager-outer'>
  <div id ='selectmanager-inner'>
    <button>Very long button name to test</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Vertically align text in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div),  [CSS Center Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block/25799339#25799339), [How to align text vertical center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Comment: if you use `top:50%;` you can use `transform:translateY(-50%)` to get the "true center"

Comment: See my comment below to Akheel K M's same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try `transform: translateY(-50%);` after you do `top:50%;`?Probably won't work on older browsers.

Comment: FYI: transform has pretty good support. See [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)

Comment: Why transform: translateY(-50%)? Won't that nullify top: 50%? When I use  just top: 50%, it goes to 1/3 from the top? When I apply both your suggestions, my button start going above the containing element.

Comment: The 50% specified in the in the translateY parameter is the 50% of the height of the element.In your case, 50% of the height of the button.

Comment: #selectmanager-inner {
  position: relative;}
button
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
} /*try adding this bit to your css.*/

Comment: This is a workable solution can also be done for horizontal alignement. Up voted.

Comment: Thanks Akheel! That worked! Applying percentages and transforms is new to me. I did the same to adjust the side and it worked for vertical alignment!

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin-top if you get the middle of both the parent container and button. For this case try

```
#selectmanager-inner .buttonclass{
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

I would apply a class to the button so that it doesn't affect all the buttons in your site.