# Unable to set height of hover overlay to 100% of container

Tags: html, css, instafeedjs

I'm using the Instafeed.js plugin and trying to style the "likes" hover overlay to fill the entire image box, however, I'm struggling to set the height to 100%.

I'm trying to avoid setting the container's height to a pixel value since the entire plugin is currently responsive.

I've looked around and tried different combinations of `display` and `position` values, but it's been mostly trial and error.

CSS:

```
#instafeed {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
#instafeed a {
  position: relative;
}
#instafeed .ig-photo {
  width: 25%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#instafeed .likes {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #f18a21;
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'LinotypeUniversW01-Thin_723604', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
  transition: opacity 100ms ease;
}
#instafeed a:hover .likes {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rc1wj5t9/

Any help/advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Although I can visit your Jsfiddle, but the Result pane is blank -- is it blank for you too?

Comment: Hmm no, I just checked and I see eight Instagram photos. Sorry, not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: I can see and use the fiddle. Trying to figure out a solution :)

Comment: #instafeed a {
    position: relative;
} is not inherit height correctly.

Comment: @0x860111 You cannot set height to an inline anchor element!! https://jsfiddle.net/bct3py0k/ , as for the author please see: http://www.korenlc.com/css-overlay-how-to-create-a-simple-css-overlay/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the anchor elements are `inline` by default, which means that they are not inheriting the height of their children `img` elements.

One possible solution is to set the `display` of the anchor elements to `inline-block`, and specify a width of `25%`. Then for the children `img` elements, set a `max-width` of `100%`:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ea12vdes/)

```
#instafeed a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 25%;
}
#instafeed .ig-photo {
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#instafeed .likes {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

To center the text, I used one of the [techniques for vertically/horizontally centering text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block/25799339#25799339) from one of my previous answers.

```
#instafeed .likes > span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation! I'll have to read up on more default `display` values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I fixed it.

CSS

```
#instafeed {
  width: 100%;
  margin:0px;
}
#instafeed a {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  width: 25%;
}
#instafeed .ig-photo {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#instafeed .likes {
  position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'LinotypeUniversW01-Thin_723604', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);  
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
    transition: opacity 100ms ease;
    z-index:10;
}
#instafeed a:hover .likes {
  opacity: 1;
}
#instafeed a:hover::after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    background: #f18a21;
    opacity:0.7;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rc1wj5t9/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your help!