# Vertically/horizontally centering a pseudo element's generated content

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone had any techniques for positioning css generated content. For example:

```css
.block {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.block:after {
  content: "content";
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

I want to center the content in the direct center of the box and none of my usual tricks are working. Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since pseudo elements are essentially added as children elements, one option is to use a [flexbox layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). Add `display: flex` to the parent element, and then use `align-items: center` for vertical centering and `justify-content: center` for horizontal centering.

```css
.block {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.block:after {
  content: "content";
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Alternatively, you could also absolutely position the element *relative* to the parent and use the [transform trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block/25799339#25799339) for vertical/horizontal centering.

```css
.block {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.block:after {
  content: "content";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position` just like you would on any other element. Make sure your `psuedo` content has `display:block;`, a defined `width` and `height`. From there you can give it `position:relative;` and any other values you would need.

http://codepen.io/RobErskine/pen/vLYZLd

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to only have text in that block and the container will be a static size you could do something like this. I'd also recommend this article https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ for more complex scenarios.

```css
.block {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.block:after {
    content: "content";
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```