# Problem with alignment of pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

The `div` with `border: 2px solid red` has 2 pseudo elements, `::before` and `::after`, each with `border-color: green` and `border-color: blue` respectively. I'm trying to align the `green` and `blue` circles in the centre of the `red` square. But unable to do so.

I've the following code:

```css
.loader-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.loader {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.loader::after,
.loader::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.loader::before {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 25%;
}

.loader::after {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: -25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-container">
  <div class='loader'></div>
</div>
```

I also searched for the solution and found these:

1. [Vertically/horizontally centering a pseudo element's generated content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34092921)
2. [Centering a pseudo element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42420062)

But they do not work for me.
Please help. Thank you.

**Edit**
The problem occurs due the different `height` and `width` of the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements. Because, when `height` and `width` of both changed to the same value, then they aligned to the centre. However, I'm trying to align them in centre while keeping the `height` and `width` of each circle distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are intrested you can simplify your code without the need of using pseudo element:

```css
.loader-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.loader {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height:102px;
  width:150px;
  background:
    /*circle with a radius of 25px and border 2px blue*/
    radial-gradient(circle at center,
      transparent 24px,blue 25px,blue 26px,transparent 27px),
    /*circle with a radius of 50px and border 2px green*/
    radial-gradient(circle at center,
      transparent 49px,green 50px,green 51px,transparent 52px);
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-container">
  <div class='loader'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Simple and best solution ever. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the box's dimensions, you can `position: absolute` the peuso-elements and then center them via the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` approach. Hope that helps.

```css
.loader-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.loader {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.loader::after,
.loader::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loader::before {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.loader::after {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-container">
  <div class='loader'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: in my code it's indeed 2px like you can see, since blue start at 25px and end at 27px but I add 1px space with the transparent color to avoir bad effect and jagged edges (in some browsers) .. it can be less than 1px if needed

Comment: @TemaniAfif Start at 25px and end at 27px is 3px. `[25, 26, 27].length === 3`

Comment: well, nevermind :x was working on some math stuffs and for me it was 27-25=2 .. need to stop doing things at the same time :s

Answer (score 1):

I've done some changes in your CSS, It works

```css
.loader-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.loader {
  border: 2px solid red;
  position relative;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.loader::after,
.loader::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.loader::before {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.loader::after {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-container">
  <div class='loader'></div>
</div>
```