# Horizontally & Vertically Center Text OVER an HTML Image (Absolute Positioning)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given the following design element, I'm attempting to include the images in html so that the opacity can be manipulated with css transitions (hover effect).

Here's my solution thus far: http://codepen.io/roachdesign/pen/VeQKJK/

The major drawback here is that I'm using a manual vertical centering (absolute / top:40%), which becomes apparent when shrinking the browser.

Is is possible to apply vertical centering with flexbox or tables when working with absolute positioning?

[image: County Badges]

HTML

```
<div class="badge-container">
  <a href="">
    <div class="badge">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x400/FF9999">
        <h2><strong>Cumberland</strong>County</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="badge">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x400/99FF99">
        <h2><strong>Dauphin</strong>County</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="badge">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x400/9999FF">
        <h2><strong>Lancaster</strong>County</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="badge">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x400/9F9F99">
        <h2><strong>Lebanon</strong>County</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="badge">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x400">
        <h2><strong>York</strong>County</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.badge-container {display:flex; flex-direction:row; 
  .badge {position:relative;}
  h2 {position:absolute;
      top:36%;
      left:0; 
      right:0;
      text-align:center;
      strong {display:block;}
  }
}

img {max-width:100%;}
```

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block/25799339#25799339). It covers multiple different approaches for vertically/horizontally centering text.

Comment: [this is a fun site too](http://howtocenterincss.com/)

Comment: For text over images try this solution: http://geekgirllife.com/place-text-over-images-on-hover-without-javascript/

Comment: @JoshCrozier I tried every one BUT the margin/translate approach, and of course it was #1 on the list lol

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use transforms

```
h2 {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%; 
  text-align:center;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

And don't forget to clear margins of `h2`
Here is a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Narek_T/c2w7p2hb/)

Comment: op SHOULD use transforms ! Unless IE8 has to be supported.

Comment: @Hritik Because of you write code in SCSS, but in codepen you choose syntax CSS. Switch to SCSS and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

you could keep using flex for h2 too

```css
.badge-container,
h2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
.badge-container .badge {
  position: relative;
}
.badge h2 {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.badge-container h2 strong {} img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="badge-container">
  <a href="">
    <div class="badge">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x400/FF9999">
      <h2><strong>Cumberland</strong>County</h2>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="">
    <div class="badge">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x400/99FF99">
      <h2><strong>Dauphin</strong>County</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="badge">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x400/9999FF">
      <h2><strong>Lancaster</strong>County</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="badge">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x400/9F9F99">
      <h2><strong>Lebanon</strong>County</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="badge">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x400">
      <h2><strong>York</strong>County</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjYQvv