# How to align text in html/css

Tags: html, css, alignment

Hi everyone Im new to HTML/CSS and was wondering how I can make something like

```
N_git_commit: 122e1  DC_git_commit: 1231
N_uptime:2190384987128421 DC_uptime: 2193821042141
```

into

```
N_git_commit: 122e1       DC_git_commit: 1231
N_uptime:2190384987128421 DC_uptime: 2193821042141enter code here
```

I currently have it set up so that each line is under one div
such as

```
<div>
  <span> N_git_commit:201213 </span>
  <span> DC_git_commit:1231  </span>
</div>
```

etc...
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In this case, a `table`

Comment: mm its more of a footer in the overall html so I don't know how a table would work

Comment: It's tabular data (at least it looks like it)...use a table.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block

Answer (score 0):

You can try `CSS Tables`

```css
.random-table {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.random-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.random-row span {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
}

.random-row > span:first-child {
  background: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="random-table">
  <div class="random-row">
    <span> N_git_commit:201213 </span>
    <span> DC_git_commit:1231  </span>
  </div>
  <div class="random-row">
    <span> N_uptime:2190384987128421 </span>
    <span> DC_uptime: 2193821042141enter </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it and it jumbled the rest of the page...not sure why, but thanks for the input!

Comment: What do you mean by `jumbled`?

Comment: Everything else on the page was overlapping with each other and nothing was in place anymore

Comment: It works better, but the table looks a little weird, but I think I can fix it if I look at the other CSS

Comment: Sorry but the table is still giving me the same issue as before...The entire thing is wrapped around a 'pull-right' class if that helps?