# Use ng-class to display some text

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class

Can I use ng-class to display text in addition to a temporary class on my div?

Here's my code.

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="setBulkMode()"

<div class="filter-nav-bar" ng-class="{'filter-nav-bar-bulk-mode': bulkMode}">
```

JS:

```
$scope.setBulkMode = function() {
                if(!$scope.bulkMode) {
                    $scope.bulkMode = true;
                } else {
                    $scope.bulkMode = false;
                }
            };
```

Whenever I'm setting bulkMode to true, on my ng-class I'd like to display some text as well. So something like...

```
<div class="filter-nav-bar" ng-class="{'filter-nav-bar-bulk-mode': bulkMode 'Bulk Mode On'">
```

But I'm not quite sure how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: inside the `div` you could just use `{{bulkMode?'Bulk Mode On' : ''}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 <div class="filter-nav-bar" ng-class="{'filter-nav-bar-bulk-mode': bulkMode">

 <span ng-show="bulkMode">Bulk Mode On</span>
```

And you dont need that function to set, you can do this easily in the view:

```
<button ng-click="bulkMode = !bulkMode">
```

Comment: Ok great. Now is there an easy way to have that text centered in the middle of my filter-nav-bar div?

Comment: For this i will leave another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block

Comment: So if I had a class just for this text: `.bulk-show {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}` Would that have to be within the filter-nav-bar css class?

Answer (score 0):

Separate it. Create a new div with the `ng-if` directive to show it conditionally:

```
<div ng-if="bulkMode">Bulk Mode On</div>
```

And also, you can better write your function (personally I would rename it to `toggleBulkMode`):

```
$scope.setBulkMode = function() {
     $scope.bulkMode = !$scope.bulkMode;
};
```