# CSS text on the middle of div (div height:20%)

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
._1{
  height:20%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
</style>
<div class="_1">content</div>
```

how to make content align at the middle of the div?
thanks.
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Pb6.png)

Edit: Height is % not px. I set `line-height: 20%` but it's not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Center text (Horizontal and Vertical) inside a DIV block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block)

Comment: @JishnuVS sir, height is % not px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   div{ 
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: center;    
  }
```

Comment: but height is % not px

Comment: @ĐặngDuyTâm fixed

Comment: Percentage values for line height are the percentage of font-size, so `20%` will not help in this case.

Comment: @DBS then how can I fix it? sir!

Comment: ok... then try to use flexbox, i'm going to change the answer

Comment: this will not work, because percentage height only take when the div is positioned , if you give position:absoulte it will work in percentage

Comment: @xale94 sir ur code work well but I can't using `text-overflow:ellipsis;`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option: Use an inner element that's vertically centred.

To do this:

- Set `._1` to `position: relative;`
- Wrap the text inside a `centerPosition` class and use the CSS for that class below.

```css
._1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  
  /* Just to make this example visible */
  border: 2px solid #555;
}

.centerPosition {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* Not needed, just making the page bigger */
.examplePage {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="examplePage">
  <div class="_1">
    <div class="centerPosition">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use flexbox, you can try using CSS3 translate. 
But in order for this to work you need to wrap your text in paragraph or some other tag:

```
._1 p{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
    position: relative;
  top: 50%;
}
<div class="_1"><p>content</p></div>
```

With that markup you can use and table-cell aligning technic as well.

Answer (score 0):

Flex-box only solution. [Here browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

```css
._1{
  height:20%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  border: 1px dashed deepskyblue;
}

html,body {
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="_1">content</div>
```

Comment: you are wellcome :)