# It is not correctly centered vertically

Tags: css

I want to center the paragraph in div "box", but vertical is not correctly centered.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #62a6c9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>center</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `top: 50%;` does not "center" an element, it only aligns it's top edge in the middle. And a `p` element has default margins from the browser stylesheet, that also influence the element position here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Center text (Horizontal and Vertical) inside a DIV block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please be sure to look for existing solutions.  This question has been asked and answered numerous times before.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your approach, the element `.box` used as a *push-down* margin is totally unnecessary, the paragraph `p` that is the element we want to keep in the middle of the `.container` should have a reset on its margins and the `.container` should have a fixed height.

Finally, use flex-boxes:

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container p {
  margin: 0;
  background: cyan;
}

.container img {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://flaviusso.altervista.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/html-css.jpg" alt="http://flaviusso.altervista.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/html-css.jpg" />
  <p>Hello World</p>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
    
  <img src="http://flaviusso.altervista.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/html-css.jpg" alt="http://flaviusso.altervista.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/html-css.jpg" />
  <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question if it's possible how can I center a text in a image if you have the image in html?
Something like that:
<div class="container">
   <img src="img.png">
   <p>center</p>
  </div>

Comment: yep, you can ask what you want!

Answer (score 0):

add `transform:translateY(-50%);  margin:0;` to the `p` to make it middle vertically

```css
.container {
       position: relative;
}

p {
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
       top: 50%;
       width: 100%;
       text-align: center;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  margin:0;
}

.box {
       width: 100%;
       height: 120px;
       background-color: #62a6c9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <p>center</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

note that your `p` is not inside `.box` currently.
You can create a fake `table`, add `display: table` to parent, and `display: table-cell` for child.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
p {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.box {
  background-color: #62a6c9;
  display: table;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <p>center</p>
  </div>
</div>
```