# Align text inside div vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

How do align the text inside a div both horizontally and vertically? I am able to align horizontally with text-align: center. But, vertical-align does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<head>
    <style>
        .blocks {
          width: 200px;
          height: 100px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          text-align: center;
          vertical-align: center;
        }
        #a1 {
          margin: 0 auto;
          margin-top: 40px;
        }
        #a2 {
          float: left;
          margin-left: 25%;
        }
        #a3 {
          float: right;
          margin-right: 25%;
        }
        #a4 {
          margin: 10% auto 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <div class="blocks" id="a1">some text</div>
    <div class="blocks" id="a2">some text</div>
    <div class="blocks" id="a3">some text</div>
    <div class="blocks" id="a4">some text</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Check this [**Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block). This question has been asked hundreds of times. Please do some research before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**. Make your `.blocks` a flex container & apply flex alignment properties `align-items` & `justify-content`. Like:

```
.blocks {
  display: flex; /* Flex Container */
  align-items: center; /* Gives Vertical Alignment */
  justify-content: center; /* Gives Horizontal Alignment */
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below (*use full screen mode*):

```css
.blocks {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#a1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
#a2 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
#a3 {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25%;
}
#a4 {
  margin: 10% auto 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <div class="blocks" id="a1">some text</div>
    <div class="blocks" id="a2">some text</div>
    <div class="blocks" id="a3">some text</div>
    <div class="blocks" id="a4">some text</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

use **css3 flexbox** concept

- set parent **display:flex**
- set child **margin:auto**

it works fine ,I'm added the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<head>
    <style>
        .blocks {
          width: 200px;
          height: 100px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          text-align: center;
          vertical-align: center;
          display:flex;
        }
        #a1 {
          margin: 0 auto;
          margin-top: 40px;
        }
        #a2 {
          float: left;
          margin-left: 25%;
        }
        #a3 {
          float: right;
          margin-right: 25%;
        }
        #a4 {
          margin: 10% auto 0;
        }
      span{
        margin:auto;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <div class="blocks" id="a1"><span>some text</span></div>
    <div class="blocks" id="a2"><span>some text</span></div>
    <div class="blocks" id="a3"><span>some text</span></div>
    <div class="blocks" id="a4"><span>some text</span></div>
    </div>
</body>
```