# Aligning position absolute div to middle?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div and a child div. The child div has the `position: absolute` property. It is already centered, but I'd like to align it to the middle of the parent div. How do I go about doing that? Here's my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o7pzvtj3/)

**HTML**

```
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='child'>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Center text (Horizontal and Vertical) inside a DIV block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` on the child div, like so:

```
#child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jwoy7rxr/

This works because the transform positions the item based on a percentage from it's own point of origin.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! With the transform property, would that work on most modern day browsers?

Comment: Support it good - but you'll need to use autoprefixer or add the vendor prefixes by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Since the parent has a height based on px, you can safely use a simple margin top and bottom to centre the element.

```
#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 115px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lr3fLser/

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the parent:

```
 #parent {
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   background-color: red;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }

 #child {
   width: 70px;
   height: 70px;
   background-color: blue;
   border-radius: 50%;
 }
```

You need the display table-cell in order to use the vertical-align.

Then add `align="center"` to the parent div's:

```
  <div align="center" id="parent">
    <div id='child'>

    </div>
 </div>
```

I have the updated JSFiddle attached:

https://jsfiddle.net/o7pzvtj3/2/