# CSS table-cell inaccurately inherited decimal value

Tags: css, sass, rounding, calc, truncated

Working on a web app project, I came across this peculiar instance where I defined a parent element's `width` as a calculated value (specifically an aspect ratio to a sass variable value). The direct child's `width` was set to `inherit`, but seemed to have truncated everything after the decimal point, leaving a fraction of a pixel's difference. It seems to only occur when the child's `display` value is set to `table-cell`, which is something I'd like to keep in order to have nicely centered text supported in all browsers (as shown in [this awesome dude's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25799339/2129271)).

Other than rounding the calculated value to a whole number or explicitly setting values to "magic numbers", is there a better solution for this?

My current solution is setting the parent's width to `ceil(#{$my-starting-value} * 16/9)` (using [Sass' ceil function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#ceil-instance_method)) and keeping the child's width as `inherit`.

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(100px * 16/9);
  
  background-color: tomato;
}

.child {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    My multiple-lined (and somewhat long) centered text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pixels cannot be broken into bits 177,7777777777778 wil be likely turned to 178px . 1 pixel is one dot of your screen :(

Comment: I get that, but that still doesn't explain how the exact value isn't accurately passed down to the child. One element reads as `177.766px` while the other reads `177px` when they should be referencing the same value. Inspect the elements in your browser's dev tools to see, if you like.

Comment: Might be a browser issue, as it displays as 178px for both parent and child in safari 10.1

Comment: @LouieBertoncin It's not the case that the value is inaccurately passed down to the child. In Chrome everything with `table-*` is for some reason not completely subpixel-aware. You can verify this by adding `display: table` to the parent and check the width of the parent (should be rounded now). Also keep in mind that when using `display: table-cell` the width property has no effect at all unless you set `display: table` and `table-layout: fixed` on the parent. Unfortunately, I can't cite from official sources nor can I provide a quickfix for this, so I just post my two cents as comment.

Comment: @Marvin haha, yeah. That's what I hoped wasn't the case. Just another awkward edge case. Yay web development! It seems like the best solution is the `ceil` one that I'm currently going with.