# Align center isn't working

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I'm trying to align the text inside my div both horizontally and vertically, but it's only aligning horizontally. Everything I try doesn't work...
here's my css code:

```
#loading > h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 21px;
  animation: fadeUpIn 3s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeUpIn 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeUpIn /* Safari and Chrome */
{
  from { opacity:0; top:150px; }
  to { opacity:1; top: 70px; }
}
#loading{
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  visibility: visible;
}
#loading.hidden{
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

My html code:

```
<div id="loading">
<h1>Creative. Simple.</h1>
</div>
```

JS fiddle of the whole website:
https://jsfiddle.net/sjyoqdqy/

Comment: [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) only aligns inline content within a parent block. It won't center a block vertically. Is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically) Also see [CSS center text (horizontally and vertically) inside a div block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block)

Comment: Yes, but everything I try doesn't work.

Comment: It might help if you show us the different things you've tried and what goes wrong. Someone might be able to help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest adding this CSS to `#loading > h1`:

```
#loading > h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 48%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Then update the animation position to be consistent:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeUpIn /* Safari and Chrome */
{
  from { opacity:0; top:58%; }
  to { opacity:1; top: 48%; }
}
```

Fiddle for an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/sjyoqdqy/6/

Comment: It seems to be working for me in the fiddle that I provided above.  What issue are you still seeing?

Comment: Id like it to have centered both vertically and horizontaly.

Comment: I've just updated my answer to include the animation position: (https://jsfiddle.net/sjyoqdqy/6/)

Answer (score -1):

```
#loading {
   ...
   display: table;
 }
#loading h1 {
   ...
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```