# How to put a text in the middle of page?

Tags: html, css

I have that html code:

```
<div id ="leftHalf">
    <div><p>CHOOSE</p></div>
</div>

<p>A</p>

<div id ="rightHalf">
    <div><p>CAT</p></div>
</div>
```

`leftHalf` is a div that occupies the left half of the screen with black background and `rightHalf` the right half in white. I just need to put a text (`<p>A</p>`) in the middle of the screen but I can't not see it. It seams that it's behind the divs.

Anyone knows how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: add your css to the question

Comment: and your js code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS center text (horizontally and vertically) inside a div block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block) and a host of other answers found by searching SO alone.

Comment: Perhaps you are interested on this: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment

Comment: Just make all three elements `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing a:

```
"text-align: center;" on your <p> tag
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/5ay5xrt4/1/ - hope this helps!