# Cannot align text to center

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align text to center (vertically and horizontally):

```
  <div class="panel-small sport">
    <b>Sport and Activity</b>
  </div>
```

this is the css:

```
.panel-small *
{
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sport
{
  background-image: url("../img/sport.png");
 left: 248px;
}
```

the text appear even on top

Comment: Do yo want to vertically align the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flex positioning:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Comment: this align only horizontally not vertically

Comment: See how this is used here: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/   This should work fine with what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this trick:

**CSS:**

```
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 90px;  /* the same as your div height */
```

Here is the complete explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5703632/5655917

Or you can use **Flexbox** with this:

**CSS:**

```
.panel-small *{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Here more explanation: https://tutorialzine.com/2015/09/quick-tip-the-simplest-way-to-center-elements-vertically-and-horizontally

Regards!