# Centering text relative to another View

Tags: javascript, react-native

How do you center the text relative to the bottom View?

[image]

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML with what you have tried.........

Comment: If it is parent then the answer in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block) question would be helpful.