# Vertically center text in div: display:flex and align-items:center not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The goal is to vertically center text in a div. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46156059/144088) suggested using `display: flex` and `align-items: center`, but it's not working.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qgOJZg

```
<div id="messageBox" style="">
   <div class="message">YO THERE THIS ROCKS!</div>
</div>


#messageBox {
    min-width: 150px;
    padding: 15px 35px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #424242;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-size: 17px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is so much to explain. But for now, just take a look at [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atzyvpce/1/).

First of all, your container has a height of its content which is your textbox and nothing more than that, so textbox is basically in the center of its container. But when you give it a `height`, you would see it's not center. Due to the nature of flex-box, it has a `flex-direction: row` by default. So you're going to change that to `column` ( which is what I had done in provided jsFiddle ), and that's pretty much it.

There were some modest changes in the structure of CSS as well, but you'll find 'em out yourself; no need to explain.

As a further investigation, `position: absolute` will make a child out of `flex-flow` like it's not a descendant at all. When you're working with `flex-box`, you don't need *absolute-positioned* elements most of the time.

Again, as another further read, please check [this great article about `flex-box` at *css-tricks.com*](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/); covered everything and super simple to learn stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Just add set your #messageBox to this

```
#messageBox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Live example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VgvEyY

Answer (score 1):

@Crashalot: by using height we can achieve but you also vertically center by using this code also.

```css
#messageBox { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.message {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  background: #424242;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="messageBox" style="">
   <div class="message">YO THERE THIS ROCKS!</div>
</div>
```