# Centering the content inside the form

Tags: html, css, forms

1) How can I center the content inside my form,both vertically and horizontally? 2) Also,how can I display the radio buttons below each other?
3) Is my form structured the right way?

```
<div class="form-calc">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="labels">
                    <label for="gender"><span>Gender:</span></label>
                </div>
                <label for="gender">
                    <input type="radio" nane="gender" id="gender" value="1">Male
                </label>

                <label for="gender">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="2">Female
                </label>

            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="labels">
                    <label for="age">
                        <span>Age:</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <input type="number" id="age" name="age">
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <div class="labels">
                    <label for="weight">
                        <span>Weight:</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <input type="number" id="weight" name="weight" placeholder="kg">
            </div>

            <div class="column">

                <div class="labels">
                    <label for="height">
                        <span>Height:</span>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <input type="number" id="height" name="height" placeholder="cm">
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <div class="labels">
                    <label for="activity">
                        <span>Activity:</span>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <select id="activity" name="activity">
                    <option value="sedentary">Sedentary (office job)</option>
                    <option value="light">Light Exercise(1-2 days/week)</option>
                    <option value="moderate">Moderate Exercise(3-5 days/week)</option>
                    <option value="heavy">Heavy Exercise(6-7 days/week)</option>
                    <option value="athlete">Athlete</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <p>
                <button>Calculate</button>
            </p>

        </fieldset>
    </form>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form-calc{
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;  
    text-align: center;  
}

.column{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.form-calc input,select {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
  }

  .form-calc input{
    width:10%;
    float:left;
}
.form-calc select{
    width:30%;
    float:left;
}

.form-calc label{
    width:30%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 30px;
  }

  .form-calc button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: white;
  }
```

That's how it looks like.I believe it's because of the floated items but I don't know of any other way to style it: 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS center text (horizontally and vertically) inside a div block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use CSS to center the contents. Please refer 
   https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp
2. You can use br tag to display the radio buttons below each other. Please refer 
   https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp
3. Yes, your form is structured good.