# Create center alignment text using HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a picture of a view of  text inside a div which is a center alignment.
The views of texts are shown as -

[image: View1]

> another example

[image: View 2]

But if I use the following code -

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
```

but this code gives me

[image]

Here is the code in jsfiddle-

https://jsfiddle.net/2bu0gym3/

How to get the desired alignment view, thanks in advance!

Comment: Give us the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS center text (horizontally and vertically) inside a div block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block)

Comment: Add some part of the code.

Comment: hi , I have updated the question with jsfiddle @M1K1O

Answer (score 1):

You have to center p itself or its parent.

```
.testimonials p ,.events P{
  margin: 0% 3%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply add:

```
p {
text-align: center
}
```

It should work. As far as I can tell, there's nothing (no class, id or something else) in your code right now that should make the text be center aligned.

Answer (score 0):

in `@media` you forgot add `.testimonials p`

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
  .testimonials img,.work-service,.testimonials p{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center !important; 
  }
```