# How do you make every text display perfectly in the center of the image?

Tags: html, css, centering

Look that every text is displayed below the picture. I would like every text to be displayed perfectly in the center of the picture.

Here is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Krzysiek_35/Ljybwz97/37/

```css
body {
  left: 8%;
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #6699cc;
}

.box3 {
    background-color: #191919;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px 40px 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #DDDDDD;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 400px;
}

.box3 > li {
    display: block;
}

.box3 > li span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box3">      
    <li>
      <img src="pictures/contact/skype.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
      <span>Skype name</span>
    </li>        
    <li>
      <img src="pictures/contact/gadu-gadu.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
      <span>Gadu-Gadu number</span>
    </li>        
    <li>
      <img src="pictures/contact/email.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
      <span>Email address</span>
    </li>        
  </div>      
</body>
```

How do you make every text display perfectly in the center of the image?

I will be very grateful for effective help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS center text (horizontally and vertically) inside a div block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
.box3 > li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `vertical-align: middle` to img:

```css
body
{
 left: 8%;
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #6699cc;
}

.box3
{
 background-color: #191919;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 15px 40px 15px;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #DDDDDD;
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 12px;
 width: 400px;
}

.box3 > li
{
 display: block;
}

.box3 > li span
{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.box3 img{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>

 <div class="box3">
  
  <li>
   <img src="pictures/contact/skype.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
   <span>Skype name</span>
  </li>
    
  <li>
   <img src="pictures/contact/gadu-gadu.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
   <span>Gadu-Gadu number</span>
  </li>
    
  <li>
   <img src="pictures/contact/email.png" width="34px" height="34px" />
   <span>Email address</span>
  </li>
    
 </div>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this also

```
.box3 > li span
{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-top:-30px;
}
```