# How to centralize text vertically and horizontally in the square

Tags: css

I used some boxes in the website below with the title Products.I want to text vertically and horizontally be in the center in the boxes (Square).Already tried:

```
display:table-cell; 
vertical-align: middle;
```

but nothing happens at all. what should i do?

website: http://www.titanotrade.com.tr/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS center text (horizontally and vertically) inside a div block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the line-height property to adjust the position of the text in your boxes e.g.

```
.title-product a {
    line-height: 270px;
}
```