# How to make smaller text size appear in middle of text line?

Tags: html, css

I have two different paragraph tags, each with a different size. The problem is that I want the two texts to move to the center of the text line, so they appear even. Below is my current code, and images of desired results. Note that these are separate tags, using `display: inline` to make the appear next to each other.

Example of current code

```css
.big {
  font-size: 42px;
  display: inline;
}

.small {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p class="big">Test</p>
<p class="small">Test</p>
```

Desired Result
[image: Desired result image]

Current Result
[image]

Comment: you can create a parent div and set its height equal to line heigt of .small https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block

Comment: You can wrap your `p` elements in a `div` and use Flexbox's `align-items: center` to vertically center the text. Here are some resources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13515693/11715889 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/31078418/11715889.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in a container element and give `vertical-align: middle;` like this

```css
.container p {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.big {
  font-size: 42px;
}

.small {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="big">Test</p>
  <p class="small">Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: we could use flexbox also to achieve the same thing, just putting it out there for to explore more about flexbox. It's really awesome in laying out elements the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
.big {
   font-size: 42px;
   display: inline;
 }

.small {
      font-size: 12px;
      display: inline;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 8px 8px;
     }
```

well while providing absolute positioning to the text of the .small class the position of the text moves to top

this might help you, also you can change the padding of  according to the font-size

Answer (score 0):

Set width to the text-box as you want. As I used display-block. You have to set display: inline-block to set the width of the text-box.

```
.text-box {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.big {
    font-size: 42px;
    display: inline;
}

.small {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline;
}
<div class="text-box">
    <p class="big">Test</p>
    <p class="small">Test</p>
</div>
```