# Bootstrap 4: align text in div vertically AND horizontally (with given div height)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to align text in a div vertically and horizontally at the same time.
Some solutions I found worked, but only when the div didn't have to stretch to the height of the parent.
After trying for quite some time to just get the vertical alignment, I somehow lost the horizontal alignment now.

I'm really lost how to make both alignments at the same time with bootstrap (and any additional CSS if needed).

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/j5xg39fb/47/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="height: 100px;">
  
    <div class="col-sm text-center bg-dark" style="align-self: stretch; align-items: center; display: flex;" >
       <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
Suchen
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm text-center bg-info " style="align-self: stretch; align-items: center; display: flex;">
      <i class="far fa-hand-pointer"></i>
      Stylisten wählen
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm text-center bg-primary" style="align-self: stretch; align-items: center; display: flex;">
      <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
      Anfrage senden
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm text-center bg-warning" style="align-self: stretch; align-items: center; display: flex;">
      <i class="far fa-smile"></i>
      Verwöhnen lassen
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you just need to use `justify-content: center;` instead of `align-self: stretch;`. Also, keep in mind when you using bootstrap there are build-in classes for flex and it's properties so you don't have to declare those manually as style. You can read more about them [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/).

So your final code should be something like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="height: 100px;">
    <div class="col-sm text-center bg-dark d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i> Suchen
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm text-center bg-info d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <i class="far fa-hand-pointer"></i> Stylisten wählen
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm text-center bg-primary d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> Anfrage senden
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm text-center bg-warning d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <i class="far fa-smile"></i> Verwöhnen lassen
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot SMAKSS! I actually tried justify-content: center; before and it didn't work for some reason. But your solutions works perfectly! Thanks a lot for the quick help! Will mark as solved once I can by system!