# Responsive depending not on screen width but on parent div width?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like the blocks below to pile on top of each other when the parent div is too small to display them on the same line.

I have tried using a @media rule with max-width but it only takes into account the width of the browser, not of the parent div.

I have tried with width instead of max-width but it did not help.

```css
.menuTwoColumns {
  display: table;
}

.menuTwoColumns > div {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

/* this only help for the browser width not the parent div width */
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .menuTwoColumns {
        display: block;
    }
    .menuTwoColumns > div {
        display:inline-block;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
<style>

</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color:grey;  width: 500px;  resize: horizontal;  overflow: auto;">
            <div class="menuTwoColumns">
                <div>
                    <p>You can resize</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>the parent div with your mouse and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it differently using flexbox

```css
.menuTwoColumns {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.menuTwoColumns > div {
  flex:calc(479px / 2);
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:grey;  width: 500px;  resize: horizontal;  overflow: auto;">
  <div class="menuTwoColumns">
    <div>
      <p>You can resize</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>the parent div with your mouse the parent div with your mouse and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text and more text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but now the vertical-align won't work anymore? (if you add more text in one of the children div)

Comment: @Pierre don't use vertical-align to center text, there is more suitable method, related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5703552/8620333