# How to change number of columns in ol list depending on parent div width?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like the list below to decrease the number of columns depending on the width of the parent div.

I have tried using a @media rule with max-width but it only takes into account the width of the browser, not of the parent div.

I have tried with width instead of max-width but it did not help.

```css
#opponentsOfCivList {
  columns: 4;
  -webkit-columns: 4;
  -moz-columns: 4;
  padding-left: 25px;
  list-style-type:disc;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  #opponentsOfCivList {
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    padding-left: 5px;
    list-style-type:disc;
  }
}
li {
  padding-left: 2px;
}
#opponentsOfCivList {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:grey; resize:horizontal; width:450px;overflow: auto;">
  <ol id="opponentsOfCivList"><li value="Phoenicia">Phoenicia</li><li value="Austria-Hungary">Austria-Hungary</li><li value="Persia">Persia</li><li value="Siam">Siam</li><li value="Maya">Maya</li><li value="Korea">Korea</li><li value="Babylonia">Babylonia</li><li value="Brazil">Brazil</li><li value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</li><li value="America">America</li><li value="Spain">Spain</li><li value="Aztec">Aztec</li><li value="Vikingland">Vikingland</li><li value="Egypt">Egypt</li><li value="Greece">Greece</li><li value="China">China</li><li value="Arabia">Arabia</li><li value="Turkey">Turkey</li><li value="Mongol">Mongol</li><li value="Inca">Inca</li><li value="Portugal">Portugal</li><li value="Rome">Rome</li><li value="Netherlands">Netherlands</li><li value="Byzantium">Byzantium</li><li value="France">France</li><li value="Germany">Germany</li><li value="India">India</li><li value="Japan">Japan</li><li value="Huns">Huns</li><li value="Russia">Russia</li><li value="England">England</li><li value="Iroquois">Iroquois</li></ol>
  <p>resize this div at the bottom right!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not yet possible until container-queries become properly supported.

Comment: you can use a grid

Comment: @s.kuznetsov you mean like here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67493774/responsive-depending-not-on-screen-width-but-on-parent-div-width/67493810

Comment: @Pierre, Almost. I have given a solution using a grid.

Comment: @Pierre, If you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: No question, just a thank you! :-)

Comment: Why not use `columns: 200px` (or any other physical value)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today, rule `columns: number column` does not allow automatic adaptation of columns to the width of the parent.

To adapt the columns, use the property function `minmax()` (*grid*), indicating the minimum and maximum values:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
```

With the indication of parameter `auto-fit`, which will allow the parent to occupy free space during resizing.

```css
#opponentsOfCivList {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    column-gap: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style-type: disc;
}

li {
    padding-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: grey; resize: horizontal; width: 450px; overflow: auto;">
    <ol id="opponentsOfCivList">
        <li value="Phoenicia">Phoenicia</li>
        <li value="Austria-Hungary">Austria-Hungary</li>
        <li value="Persia">Persia</li>
        <li value="Siam">Siam</li>
        <li value="Maya">Maya</li>
        <li value="Korea">Korea</li>
        <li value="Babylonia">Babylonia</li>
        <li value="Brazil">Brazil</li>
        <li value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</li>
        <li value="America">America</li>
        <li value="Spain">Spain</li>
        <li value="Aztec">Aztec</li>
        <li value="Vikingland">Vikingland</li>
        <li value="Egypt">Egypt</li>
        <li value="Greece">Greece</li>
        <li value="China">China</li>
        <li value="Arabia">Arabia</li>
        <li value="Turkey">Turkey</li>
        <li value="Mongol">Mongol</li>
        <li value="Inca">Inca</li>
        <li value="Portugal">Portugal</li>
        <li value="Rome">Rome</li>
        <li value="Netherlands">Netherlands</li>
        <li value="Byzantium">Byzantium</li>
        <li value="France">France</li>
        <li value="Germany">Germany</li>
        <li value="India">India</li>
        <li value="Japan">Japan</li>
        <li value="Huns">Huns</li>
        <li value="Russia">Russia</li>
        <li value="England">England</li>
        <li value="Iroquois">Iroquois</li>
    </ol>
    <p>resize this div at the bottom right!</p>
</div>
```

Solution using `columns: width value`, specifying column widths in pixels:

```
columns: 100px;
```

```css
#opponentsOfCivList {
    columns: 100px;
    column-gap: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style-type: disc;
}

li {
    padding-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: grey; resize: horizontal; width: 450px; overflow: auto;">
    <ol id="opponentsOfCivList">
        <li value="Phoenicia">Phoenicia</li>
        <li value="Austria-Hungary">Austria-Hungary</li>
        <li value="Persia">Persia</li>
        <li value="Siam">Siam</li>
        <li value="Maya">Maya</li>
        <li value="Korea">Korea</li>
        <li value="Babylonia">Babylonia</li>
        <li value="Brazil">Brazil</li>
        <li value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</li>
        <li value="America">America</li>
        <li value="Spain">Spain</li>
        <li value="Aztec">Aztec</li>
        <li value="Vikingland">Vikingland</li>
        <li value="Egypt">Egypt</li>
        <li value="Greece">Greece</li>
        <li value="China">China</li>
        <li value="Arabia">Arabia</li>
        <li value="Turkey">Turkey</li>
        <li value="Mongol">Mongol</li>
        <li value="Inca">Inca</li>
        <li value="Portugal">Portugal</li>
        <li value="Rome">Rome</li>
        <li value="Netherlands">Netherlands</li>
        <li value="Byzantium">Byzantium</li>
        <li value="France">France</li>
        <li value="Germany">Germany</li>
        <li value="India">India</li>
        <li value="Japan">Japan</li>
        <li value="Huns">Huns</li>
        <li value="Russia">Russia</li>
        <li value="England">England</li>
        <li value="Iroquois">Iroquois</li>
    </ol>
    <p>resize this div at the bottom right!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is technically incorrect. `columns` accepts a physical width (e.g: `columns: 12em`). And by that I'm not saying the `grid` solution is not better. Just that, technically, one could adapt the number of columns to parent width, and you claimed the opposite.

Comment: @tao I don't understand, could you propose an answer with a working code? I tried `columns: 200px` and `columns: 12em` by curiosity, but it didn't achieve anything.

Comment: @Pierre, He meant to use a width of `columns`. This will work too. Check pls out my second snippet.

Comment: @tao, Technical incorrect answer? What are you talking about, mate? The `auto-fit` parameter is exactly what allows the elements to stretch to the width of the parent. The `auto-fit` parameter is exactly what allows the elements to stretch to the width of the parent. Look pls at this sandbox - https://codepen.io/SaraSoueidan/pen/JrLdBQ.

Comment: The technically incorrect bit is the one suggesting *"[columns](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-multicol-1/#columns) does not allow automatic adaptation of columns to the width of the parent"*. It's incorrect because if you use a physical measurement (e.g: `200px`) as the value of `columns` the number of columns changes depending on parent width. When parent is < `400px` it has 1 column, above that it has 2, above `600px` 3, etc... Which part is unclear, *"mate"*?

Comment: Also, please re-read my first comment: I said there (implicitly) that I consider the provided `grid` solution a proper one for this type of problem. I simply wanted to point out that the wording was not technically correct. `columns` CSS property does allow a basic form of adaptation to the parent width. We shouldn't claim the opposite. I'm basically waiting for the answer to no longer contain any untrue claim, so I can upvote it. :)

Comment: Thanks s.kuznetsov for the new snippet. @tao: the wording is currently "*rule columns: **number column** does not allow automatic adaptation of columns to the width of the parent.*" so I think it's correct as it is, respecting what you are saying