# How to center text, if there is item at the right of line

Tags: html, css, sass

[image]

Here is what I want to get.
The black part is the container div. width 100%
The blue part is the main header text div,
And the pink one is the button that should be placed at the right of the container div.

Question: How to center header text, so it will be the center of the container div, not the center of the blue part? My problem is when I give the pink button position: absolute; that button keeps floating while scrolling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I center text (horizontally and vertically) inside a div block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/how-can-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block)

Comment: No, because I got a button from the right, which is troublemaking using the usual centering forms

Comment: can you post your code and real scenario pic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid darkgrey;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.header__title {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.header__button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <h3 class="header__title">Header text here</h3>
  <button class="header__button">Button</button>
</header>
```

Of course you can change the background colors, border, padding, margins, ... to fit your design. This is just to illustrate where the elements are.

The key here was to use `position: absolute` on the button.

`position: absolute` remove the element (the button) from the document flow, so the other element (the header text) can be centered on 100% width of the page.

Some good information about position absolute [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: @R_M i have update the unswer, there was a typo

Comment: Yess, after the update it works, thanks a lot !