# How to center text inside container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to center text inside a container?
The methods in this thread are not working for me.
[How can I center text (horizontally and vertically) inside a div block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/how-can-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block)

I want the text to be vertically centered but horizontally adjacent to the left edge.

Comment: `.container {display: flex; align-items: center}`

Comment: @zer00ne Then, for example, a span element will be centered, but the text inside it will not.

Comment: Apply the same style to the `<span>` as well. If you'd like the `<span>` to be able to sit next to another element then use `display:inline-flex` instead of `display: flex`.