# How to center a div with 2 photos ,one covering another in mobile screen resolution

Tags: html, css, image, overlay

I tried to center a div with 2 photos exactly in the center. However it didn't go well. Tried different types of positioning, display flex, align items justify content, etc, nothing allows me to
move image container to the center.

Here is my code:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.section {
  padding: 4.5rem 0 2rem;
}

.home_container {
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.home_images {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.home_big-img {
  z-index: 12;
}

.home_small-img {
  transform: translateX(-9rem);
}
```

```html
<section class="section home grid">
  <div class="home_container container">
    <div class="home_images">
      <img src="./img/man.png" alt="" class="home_big-img">
      <img src="./img/plane.png" alt="" class="home_small-img">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here is first image:

[image]

And here is second one:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] please?

Comment: can you provide sketch in paint/figma how exactly do u want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I center text (horizontally and vertically) inside a div block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/how-can-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block)

Comment: @trysetyoutomo
 There you go link https://www.figma.com/file/u9gJMBfNQXpEeXMyUZ5bBr/Urelocation-v2-~10000-12000-(Copy)?node-id=1548%3A213&mode=dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center child elements (img in your case) in a parent element, you should:

1. Give your parent element a correct width and height
2. Apply **position: relative**, **display: flex**, **align-items: center** and **justify-content: center** to your parent element (**.home-images** in your case)
3. Apply **position: absolute** to your child elements

```css
section {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.images {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.big-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.small-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section class="home">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="images">
      <img class="big-img"/>
      <img class="small-img"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

```
.home_images{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);

}
```

In case you want to make it vertically center, use **translateY** instead of **translateX** and **top: 50%** instead of **left: 50%**

Answer (score 0):

To center the images, you can use flexbox.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}
    
.section {
  padding: 4.5rem 0 2rem;
}
    
.home_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
    
.home_images {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
    
.home_big-img {
  z-index: 12;
}

.home_small-img {
  transform: translateX(-9rem);
}
```

In the modified code, I removed the position: absolute from the .home_images class and replaced it with display: flex, align-items: center, and justify-content: center in the .home_container class to center the entire image container on the screen. I also set the height of the container to 100vh to make sure it takes up the full viewport height.

Save the changes, and the images should now be centered on the mobile screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.section {
  padding: 4.5rem 0 2rem;
}

.home_container {
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.home_images {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.home_big-img {
  z-index: 12;
}

.home_small-img {
  transform: translateX(-9rem);
}
```

```html
<section class="section home grid">
  <div class="home_container container">
    <div class="home_images">
      <img src="./img/man.png" alt="" class="home_big-img">
      <img src="./img/plane.png" alt="" class="home_small-img">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).