# trying to make a 3 steps program for the user

Tags: html, css, ejs

I'm trying to get responsive circles, with the same width and height, and also I want the horizontal line to be centered in the center.
and the numbers will also we centered in the middle of the circle, does somebody know how I can change this to accomplish that?

```css
.DCQ_Container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.Progress_Bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px solid royalblue;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

.HR_line {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  flex-grow: 0.1;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="DCQ_Container">
  <h1 class="Steps_Head"> DCQ Step 1 / 3 </h1>
  <div class="Progress_Bar">
    <div class="Circle_Text_Container">
      <div class="circle">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
      <p>User Name</p>
    </div>
    <hr class="HR_line" />
    <div class="Circle_Text_Container">
      <div class="circle">
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
      <p>Location</p>
    </div>
    <hr class="HR_line" />
    <div class="Circle_Text_Container">
      <div class="circle">
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
      <p>Buisnesss</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make the circles flex containers too.

Comment: thank you this is fixed the text to the center, but not my hr's not straighted

Answer (score 1):

You could bring titles out of flex flow:

```css
.Circle_Text_Container {
  position: relative; /* Creates context for absolute in children */
}

.Circle_Text_Container > p {
  position: absolute; /* Relative to last element with postition set to relative */
  top: 100%; /* Distance from top */
}
```

That makes flex size equal to height of circle.

To center text in circles, you can also use flex:

```css
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: green;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

BTW, there are multiple ways of centering content in div. So many, that it kind of became a meme. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/how-can-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-a-div-block) is StackOverflow Question about this problem.

So final effect would look like this:

```css
.DCQ_Container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.Progress_Bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px solid royalblue;
  align-items: center;
}

.Circle_Text_Container {
  position: relative; /* Creates context for absolute in children */
}

.Circle_Text_Container > p {
  position: absolute; /* Relative to last element with postition set to 
relative */
  top: 100%; /* Distance from top */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.HR_line {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  flex-grow: 0.1;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="DCQ_Container">
  <h1 class="Steps_Head"> DCQ Step 1 / 3 </h1>
  <div class="Progress_Bar">
    <div class="Circle_Text_Container">
      <div class="circle">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
      <p>User Name</p>
    </div>
    <hr class="HR_line" />
    <div class="Circle_Text_Container">
      <div class="circle">
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
      <p>Location</p>
    </div>
    <hr class="HR_line" />
    <div class="Circle_Text_Container">
      <div class="circle">
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
      <p>Buisnesss</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also change how much text extends labels extend before and after circle by adjusting left and right property on Circle_Text_Container > p.